# Embedding files into a PDF document with dvipdfmx

Tags: pdf, embedding, dvipdfmx

I use the `embedfile` package in order to embed the LaTeX source code into the final PDF with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{embedfile}
\embedfile{\jobname.tex}

\begin{document}
The document
\end{document}
```

This works fine with `pdflatex`, but now I have to switch to XeLaTeX in order to use a custom TrueType font. However, the `embedfile` package doesn't support the program `dvipdfmx` used by XeLaTeX. Is there a way to modify the package to make it cooperate with `dvipdfmx`, or another package with similar functionality supporting this driver?

(This question is similar, but not identical, to
[Attach files to PDF with dvipdfmx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3512/attach-files-to-pdf-with-dvipdfmx): In the answers to this question, a way to **attach** a file to a PDF using `dvipdfmx` is shown. This creates a visible icon in the document, which is not what I want: The embedded file should only appear in the list of attachments displayed e.g. by Acrobat Reader.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I figured it out myself: The package [navigator](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/navigator) works fine with `pdflatex` and `dvipdfmx` and supports embedding files through the `\embeddedfile` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{navigator}
\embeddedfile{sourcecode}{\jobname.tex}

\begin{document}
The document
\end{document}
```

The syntax of the command is

```
\embeddedfile[<optional description>]{<object name>}[<optional filename displayed in the viewer>]{<file>}
```

Answer (score 5):

Heiko Oberdiek has updated `attachfile2` package to support dvipdfmx and XeTeX. Use this version:

http://www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~oberdiek/tmp/attachfile2.pdf

(The `attachfile2.dtx` is attached in the pdf file.)

To avoid the icon, you can use `\textattachfile` command. For example:

```
\textattachfile{foo.jpg}{} % no icon or text
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to embed a file using this package without creating a visible icon in the document as described in my question. However, I came across the [navigator](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/navigator) package, which implements exactly what I need - see my own answer.

Comment: @diabonas: `\textattachfile{filename}{}` should work.

Comment: On 2011-04-12, the [latest `attachfile2` version was uploaded to CTAN](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.ctan.announce/8568), so you can now install the version supporting `dvipdfmx` by simply updating your TeX distribution. The temporary download link mentioned above doesn't exist any more.

Comment: Giving an example would probably help; the link is dead.