# Is there some way to embed LaTeX source code in a PDF file?

Tags: pdf, embedding, source, attachfile

Several times now I have inadvertently lost the .tex file that generated a PDF file with `pdflatex`. Given what I know of the internal structure of PDF files, it should be possible to embed a text file containing the original LaTeX file into the PDF file so that it can be extracted later.

I am aware of no technology for doing this, but perhaps you are. Does anybody have something like this?

Comment: I'd never thought of doing that, but it's a really good idea!

Comment: [LaTeXiT](http://pierre.chachatelier.fr/programmation/latexit_en.php), a small utility for MacOS does this. It is a tool to typeset formulas or other stuff (I use it mostly for small TikZ-Figures) in LaTeX and to directly copy the resulting (cropped) PDF into other applications, such as Keynote or Powerpoint. The cool thing is that it embeds the source code into the PDF, so if you, some day later, copy it back into LaTeXiT, you can edit the image.

Comment: That is super-cool. Thanks for telling me about LaTeXiT

Comment: If you want to embed the source but keep it secret, use this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34204/1871.

Comment: LaTeXiT appears to do this by storing metadata inside the PDF file. That's different, but it's still super-cool.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The package [embedall](https://ctan.org/pkg/embedall) has been made exactly for that:

Just include

```
\usepackage{embedall}
```

just before `\begin{document}` and it will embed all graphics, listings, and the tex source.

**side note:** The CTAN tag [archival](https://ctan.org/topic/archival) has more related tools listed. For instance, [mkjobtexmf](https://ctan.org/pkg/mkjobtexmf) saves all `.sty` files. They could be embedded in the PDF, but I am unsure whether that's overkill. The package [skb](https://ctan.org/pkg/skb) proposes a new kind of workflow, which does not really seem to tackle your issue.

Comment: This is now the correct answer! Yea!

Comment: You're welcome! I just added a link to `archival`, because one could find the related tooling `mkjobtexmf` interesting, too. Hlpe, you like it, too.

Comment: It's a pity that it has only 6 upvotes while other answers have many upvotes

Comment: It should be noted that `embedall` relies on the `embedfile` package, and so it only works with pdfTeX and LuaTeX ([added in `embedfile` v2.7](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/embedfile.pdf)). There is no XeTeX support at the moment.

Answer (score 69):

I would recommend the [`embedfile`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/embedfile) or the [`navigator`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/navigator) package (the latter has the additional advantage of working together with `dvipdfmx`, see [this question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10319/embedding-files-into-a-pdf-document-with-dvipdfmx)). Both are quite similar in usage:

With the `embedfile` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{embedfile}
\embedfile{\jobname.tex}

\begin{document}
The document
\end{document}
```

With the `navigator` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{navigator}
\embeddedfile{sourcecode}{./\jobname.tex}

\begin{document}
The document
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice! This seems better than `attachfile` since it doesn't insert any objects on the page. Note, however, that you need `./\jobname.tex` for `xdvipdfmx`, as explained in the question I linked to earlier.

Comment: @Andrey The above code for the `navigator` package works fine with my `xelatex` version (which relies on `xdvipdfmx`, version `0.7.8`). Maybe the `navigator` package takes care of the relative path issue automatically?

Comment: @diabonas: It doesn't work here with `xdvipdfmx` version 0.7.8, TeX Live 2010, though. My TeX Live [comes](http://packages.gentoo.org/package/app-text/texlive) from Gentoo, so it might have different configuration than the one used by the official TeX Live installer.

Comment: @Andrey That's quite strange - the same version of the program producing different results? You have convinced me, however, to add the `./` to my answer to be sure that it works `:-)`

Comment: This worked, but how do I get the embedded file out of my pdf?

Comment: @Seamus Adobe Reader shows the files embedded/attached to the PDF file in the attachment tab - in the most recent version (Adobe Reader X), you open it by clicking the paper clip icon in the left side bar. As an alternative, you can use [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) to do the extraction on the command line: `pdftk file.pdf unpack_files output ~/folder/`

Comment: Wow. Works like a charm.

Comment: I just asked the question of how to also password protect the attached file so no one can access to the source, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26067/is-it-possible-to-embed-attach-a-file-password-protected-in-a-pdf

Comment: Important note: At the moment, `embedfile` only works with pdfTeX and (since 2016) LuaTeX. There is no XeTeX support. (`navigator` seems to work with all three.)

Answer (score 28):

You can attach arbitrary files to a PDF document using the [`attachfile2`](http://ctan.org/pkg/attachfile2) package.

The above package works only with pdfTeX and `dvips`. For a XeTeX/`xdvipdfmx` solution, see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3512) question.

Comment: I was just drafting much the same answer. The OP might also want to look at the original `attachfile` package for details of the basic options (basically use `\attachfile`!).

Comment: Well, I tried attachfile2 and just wasn't able to get it to work properly because of Unicode issues.

Answer (score 13):

You can do this in ConTeXt as well. Example:

```
\setupinteraction [state=start]
\starttext
Foo \attachment[file=attachfile.tex, title=Some file, author=Me]
\stoptext
```

[image: result]

The `file` key contains the file name, the `title` key is used (probably depending on the reader) e.g. for a tool tip (see screenshot). Interaction needs to be activated, otherwise the attachment mechanism don't work.

Answer (score 1):

The question has already been answered, but I would like to add a warning:

Strategies for embedding the source code may run afoul of PDF/X, and possibly also PDF/A. So, if your file must be PDF/X or PDF/A, be careful.

Rationale: PDF/X is intended for reliable print. Any non-printing content, or scripted content, violates the spec. PDF/A is intended for archiving and also (depending on level) accessibility. Non-visible content may violate the accessibility spec.

If I had a "one size fits all" answer, I would provide it.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Even the PDF/X standards from 2003 allow embedded files. Yes, JavaScript and links are forbidden but embedding is not. An embedded `.icc`file is even one of the key features of a PDF/X, isn't it?