# Can I recover my .tex file?

Tags: conversion, auxiliary-files, metadata

I have lost my tex file but I still have my pdf, `.aux`, `.bak`, `.bbl`, performance monitor file, and my text document.

Can anyone tell me if I can restore my `.tex` file from this? In any form?

Addition by Jake:
Note that this question is not a direct duplicate of [How to convert PDF to (La)TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/how-to-convert-pdf-to-latex), since that question is concerned only with converting PDF to `.tex` without any of the additional files that are available in this case.

Comment: What tool/editor are you using? If the `.bak` file is from the `.tex` file than it should contain the last version of it. Not sure what you mean with "text document" because that's usually the `.tex` file.

Comment: "text document" probably is the .log file; that's what Windows usually calls this file type.

Comment: @Thorsten I'd say no, since even if the answers are the same the question is very different.

Comment: Also how did you lose it? If you stop using your computer and run a disk recovery tool you might be able to get it back.

Comment: @Canageek We closed a similar question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72772/lost-latex-file-but-served-pdf-file

Comment: @Canageek Try vote for reopening, this is not a duplicate question.

Comment: Hi Everybody, Thanks for your suggestions but the .bak file is a back up of the bibtex file rather than the .tex file.

Comment: @MartinScharrer I have installed TexMakerX and TEXnicCenter but I only use TEXnicCenter. Thanks!

Comment: @Janet Then you have to follow the procedure in on of the referred question (also have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72772/lost-latex-file-but-served-pdf-file/72775#72775).

Comment: @Janet I assume your 'performance monitor file, and my text document' files have extension `.blg` and `.log`, respectively. If so, they are both log files, one for BibTeX and one for LaTeX, and don't really help out with 'reconstruction'.

Comment: @Jake The availability of the auxiliary files probably makes little difference to the ease of recover. They are really dependent on the `.tex` file (we have no mention of a `.bib` file, which would have more value as it's a source file). As such, the problem here does seem to boil down to getting the text back out of a PDF.

Comment: @JosephWright: I guess that should be posted as an answer, then?

Answer (score 9):

Broadly, the problem outlined here is the same as [How to convert PDF to (La)TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/how-to-convert-pdf-to-latex). The reason is that at best the various additional files contain only a small subset of the information needed to understand the structure of the `.tex` source file. I don't want to repeat all of the info in [File extensions related to LaTeX, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7770/file-extensions-of-latex-related-files), but as a summary:

- The `.log` and `.blg` files are logs: they tell us what happened in the LaTeX and BibTeX runs, respectively. That will be useful in working out which packages were used in the `.tex` file,  but that alone does not get us very far (no custom settings or actual input).
- The `.bbl` file may help with the bibliography part of the document. If you did *not* using `biblatex` then the `.bbl` file is a formatted bibliography, but if you used `biblatex` then it's not. Moreover, it does not help with the citations that link to the bibliography, and most of the time the bibliography will be a relatively small part of the entire document.
- The `.aux` file tells us about information transferred  between LaTeX runs, so for example labels used in the `.tex` file, but not where they might have been cross-referenced, *etc.*

As you'll see, the amount of information in the various additional files is at best quite limited, and in most real documents will form only a small part of what's needed to reconstruct the `.tex` source. Thus there will still be a lot of work to do extracting data from the `.pdf`, and it may well be easier to ignore the other files and 'start from scratch', reconstruction-wise.

Answer (score 4):

i was using texmaker and I had similar accident.
Go to File > Session > restore previous session

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!