# How can I recover the source code when TikZEdt crash?

Tags: bugs, wysiwyg

Sometimes TikZEdt crashes because of some bugs in the program, and I did not save the source file.

Is there a way to recover the source code in that case?

---

Related questions:

- [conversion - Can I recover my .tex file? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73538/can-i-recover-my-tex-file)

  If you have the PDF file for some reason (quite unlikely with TikZEdt) that can be used with limited success.
- [editors - What You See is What You Get (WYSIWYG) for PGF/TikZ? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24235/what-you-see-is-what-you-get-wysiwyg-for-pgf-tikz)

  TikZEdt is (at the time this post is written) unmaintained, the alternative is to use something else so it's less likely to crash again.

Comment: Unfortunately, TikZEdt hasn't been maintained for years. I suggest to you to use another tool or an online compiler like Overleaf.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Yes I know unfortunately, that's why it crashes.

Comment: It's a pity, because it was a great tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TikZEdt usually have continuous compilation on, and it stores the temporary TeX file for compilation in the temporary folder.

In some operating systems the path is `/tmp/`. Search for the most recently edited TeX files there, the file name could be `TE_temp_preview12345.tex`.