# Is TeX code obtainable from other output files

Tags: auxiliary-files

Unfortunetely, all my TeX code within one of my .tex files got deleted. However, I still have all other output files from the compilation process of this specific .tex file.

Is there any way I can get the actual TeX code back from these files, or am I doomed to write it all over again?

Comment: In general: No. The auxiliary files do not contain enough information to recover our `.tex` source. The PDF has the printable text, so you can probably salvage most of that with a tool like `pdftotext `. But of course all the markup commands are gone.

Comment: Some editors sometimes save backups of files that are being edited. Look closely in the directory of your `.tex` file for files called `.tex.bak` or `.tex~` or some such.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73538/82917

Comment: @moewe Thanks alot! I'm using Texmaker as an editor... Seems to me that no such backup files have been created.