# Is it possible to get the source code of a LaTeX rendered PDF file if one has the hard copy?

Tags: pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert PDF to (La)TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/how-to-convert-pdf-to-latex)
>   [Lost LaTeX-file - but served pdf - File](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72772/lost-latex-file-but-served-pdf-file)

I know there are a couple of apps floating around where you can get the source code if you handwrite the equations, but is it possible to reveal the source code from a hard copy of a latex rendered document?

edit: by hard copy i mean literally a paper copy.

Comment: If by hard-copy, you're meaning a pdf or equivalent, then see here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72772/lost-latex-file-but-served-pdf-file

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate: every method that gets LaTeX source code from a paper copy is also method to get LaTeX source code from a pdf file. Also: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) `:)`. We tend to close duplicate questions in order to keep all the answers to the same question in one place. However, we still keep the closed questions around as pointers to the "original" question. Let us know if you have any questions or concerns about the closing of this question.

Comment: A hard copy (a true **paper** copy) may require an additional step of OCR...