# Is there any way to convert a pdf file back to lyx file?

Tags: lyx

Is there any way to convert a pdf file back to lyx file

Comment: Hi, welcome. If you mean that you have a PDF previously generated by LyX, and you want the original `.lyx` file back, then no, there is no way of doing that. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85683/is-it-possible-to-get-the-source-code-of-a-latex-rendered-pdf-file-if-one-has-th and linked questions for example.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Sorry, there's no easy way.

You may export the PDF into HTML and import the latter in LyX. Results depend on complexity of the layout.

With packages like 'embedfile' or 'attachfile' you may add your *.lyx source to the PDF. Next time no need to ask such questions …