# Is there a way to extract the source .tex from a pdf file?

Tags: pdf

I have a pdf file that I'm positive was originally set up in TeX. Is there a way to extract the original markup from this?

If it's any help, I work with Windows 7 and MikTeX 2.9

Comment: The PDF format does not contain any information about the producing source (except in the document properties). Hence this will be as successful as trying to extract the ingredients from a cake. You only can export the textual content and post-process it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Short answer: No. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72772/lost-latex-file-but-served-pdf-file and related questions.

Comment: that is only possible if the source itself is attaches to the pdf.

Comment: I usually say that it's the same problem as extracting apples from an apple pie.

Comment: @canaaerus You are pointing to a duplicate as a reason. I think it's good archival practice if we follow the chain to the end.

Comment: @percusse: You are confusing the two comments. The reason for the duplicate is a non-duplicate question. For the other comment you are correct, I'll correct that.

Comment: Exactly, Herbert, and that was discussed in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13187/is-there-some-way-to-embed-latex-source-code-in-a-pdf-file.

Comment: The conversion question seems to me to be different, though related. This question specifically asks about recovering the *original* source, whereas that question is about anyway to convert pdf to tex format. Although the answers there imply the answers here, they are not the same question and this one would be turned up by different searches than that one.