# Embed distributed LaTeX file/code to the PDF?

Tags: pdf, input, sourcecode, embedding

I have read of the possibility to embed the LaTeX source in a generated PDF, see the question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13187/is-there-some-way-to-embed-latex-source-code-in-a-pdf-file).

Do you know of a way to do this with **distributed** TeX file, i.e. for a TeX file which is stored in many separate parts and put together using `include` an `input`?

I'd rather not have to manually include all the `.tex` files, as this will surely at some point lead to me forgetting one of the many files (think title.tex, acknowledgment.tex, abstract.tex, chapter1.tex, ..., appendix1.tex, ...,backmatter.tex, etc...).

Comment: How about adding a zip file with all the LaTeX (and other) sources. Depending on what build system and/or versioning system you use, it may help you automate the task.

Comment: +1 for zipping -- in fact, any sort of archive system (`tar` comes to mind) would be the best solution here, IMO.  You don't want your consumer to have to fiddle with the directory structure of your project -- it's asking for headaches.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: [Create list of all external files used by master LaTeX document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24542/create-list-of-all-external-files-used-by-master-latex-document)

Comment: Though I also would prefer the ZIP file embedding, you can embed more than one file, the regarding packages are `attachfile2` and `embedfile` depending of what you really want to do.

Comment: Has anyone an idea how I could automate the creation/inclusion of an archive? Bonus points if the solution is configuration-free (on the editor side) and/or works with pure LaTeX...

(I know this is probably possible by creating a makefile and using that to compile my TeX, but if possible I'd rather use something that does not require me to change config in every editor I use, i.e. something that works with pdflatex...)

Comment: Ok, this is a **problem**: Adobe does not allow `.zip` files as attachments. Or rather, the attachment can be embedded, but Acrobat Reader doesn't allow you to open and/or save the attached file later on - which is the whole bloody point of attaching the `.zip` in the first place...

Comment: @fgysin: Let me guess: Zip files are thought to be a security problem?

Comment: Yes. And of course users are so irresponsible that they can't even be trusted with a choice to open the `.zip` file... Just does not work anymore. -.-

Comment: @fgysin, simply change the file ending to "txt" and have a note tell about the ending change before doing anything. :)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26067/is-it-possible-to-embed-attach-a-file-password-protected-in-a-pdf?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to summarize all that was stated in the comments, there seems to be a few things you can try:

1) If you want to include **files** then you can use tar or any other compression method to include everything in a single folder.  Of course this could lead to you forgetting some of the files, but if you are organized you shouldn't have any problems.

2) You could use the `attachfile2` and `embedfile` packages, as described by speravir

3) As per question [Is there some way to embed LaTeX source code in a PDF file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13187/is-there-some-way-to-embed-latex-source-code-in-a-pdf-file?rq=1), `navigator` is another package you may use.

4) As [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51467/27833) to question mentioned in 3), you can try using ConTeXt