# Did anyone succeed in playing embedded movies inside Acrobat in Linux?

Tags: animations, movie15, acrobat, media9

Some time ago I asked this question [How to include a movie in a PDF? Step by step instructions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60646/how-to-include-a-movie-in-a-pdf-step-by-step-instructions). (I tried everything documented there, and links therein. I can't find the combination of tools to be able to playback embedded movies in a PDF viewer in Linux.)

This time I am going to be more direct: Was anyone, with a certain combination of tools and viewer, able to create a PDF from TeX with an embedded movie and play it back in a Linux viewer (for example some version of Acrobat)?

If, so what package, tex version, acrobat version was used?

---

**EDIT 2014**

Thanks to @AlexG, great advances have been made regarding the inclusion of movies and in particular the playback in Linux. It is just a pity that Acrobat for Linux is at its end of life (not so much for Adobe but because nobody is picking up the torch for embedded media).

This edit simply summarizes a working solution that is illustrated by defining a command `\includemove[dimensions]{moviewithoutextension}`, that produces movies that can be played back in Acrobat 9.4.1 (Linux), Acrobat for Windows and Mac and that fallbacks to external players (and a still picture) in other PDF viewers.

Assumptions:

1. You have a copy of jw-player 5.10 (`not 5.9 or 6.x`) in your local directory and it is named `player.swf`. (from here http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/browser/tags/mediaplayer-5.10, documentation here: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw5/31138/configuration-options)
2. You have `ffmpeg` version 2.1.4.
3. You have a copy of your movie in the `mp4` format. Any movie can be converted in this way

   `ffmpeg -i $MYMOVIE.vid -vf scale="trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 25 -r 25 $MYMOVIE.mp4`

   <s>`ffmpeg -i $MYMOVIE.vid -qscale 0 -vcodec libx264 -x264opts keyint=25 $MYMOVE.mp4`</s>
4. A preview image with the same name but extension `png`. This can be achieved by converting your movie in this way and taking an snapshot:

   `ffmpeg -i $MYMOVIE.mp4 -ss 00:00:2.1 -f image2 -vframes 1 $MYMOVIE.png`
5. [optional] A PDF image with the same name but `pdf` extension to replace the PNG preview in case Flash content is not active.
6. You are OK using the packages `hyperref` (and `media9` of course).
7. [for playback] You have Acrobat 9.4.1 (for playback in Linux) or more modern versions in other systems.
8. [for playback] For other PDF viewers: the extension `mp4` is associated with some application and the movie is distributed with the PDF.

Limitations (of my poor implementation, not of `media9`)

1. Only `width` and/or `height` can be specified as options.
2. No other player than `jw-player` can be used (options are hardcoded in the command definition).
3. It assumes a lot of defaults regarding the behavior of the embedded player.
4. [For fallback] The definition tries it best to have a nice fallback mode for other viewers, and you have to choose (see the code) between embedding the movie or having an external file.
5. [For playback] I don't know if it works in all viewers, it works at least in Acrobat 9.4.1 (Linux) and Evince 3.10.3 (Linux). I saw it work in Acrobat X in Windows and Mac after a "security message" confirmation.

Given this conditions, the following document that includes the definition of `\includemovie` and summarizes a working solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noplaybutton]{media9}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{attachfile2}

\newcommand{\includemovie}[2][]{
    \includemedia[
        #1,
        activate=pageopen,transparent,
        addresource=#2.mp4,addresource=#2.png,
        flashvars={
            file=#2.mp4&image=#2.png&
            stretching=uniform&start=0&
            screencolor=white& %improves render in light backgrounds
            controlbar.position=over&controlbar.idlehide=true&
            autostart=true&repeat=always&smoothing=true
            %&bufferlength=10 % may improve repetition of short videos
        }
    ]{ % for disabled content (in most cases this is fallback)
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            \mbox{
            %   \href{run:#2.mp4} % for not embedded fallback
                \textattachfile[color={0 0 0}]{#2.mp4} % for embedded fallback
                {\texttt{|\kern-.23em>}} % poor play button
            } & \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}
        \end{tabular}
    }{player.swf}
}

\begin{document}

\includemovie[width=5cm]{MYMOVIE} %no extension!

\end{document}
```

(note: you may benefit by producing `JPEG` snapshots, `PNG` are usually very big, sometimes as big as the whole movie)

Comment: The `ffmpeg` command line to produce a usable video file, item (3), may need to be adjusted. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141765.

Comment: At least `-profile:v high  -pix_fmt yuv420p` should be added to the `ffmpeg` command line to get a usable MP4 video file (item 3 of your list).

Comment: Thanks, my `ffmpeg` is complaining that `qscale` is ambiguous. *Do you have a complete line to suggest?* (feel free to edit). BTW, I never had problems using this command line (in spite of not understanding some of the options).

Comment: See the link in my first comment. It also adds an option to ensure even pixel numbers in both video dimensions. Recent `libx264`versions seem to use a different profile/pix format which is not compatible with Flash Player.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update**

As of 2013/11/04, package `media9` contains media player Flash components `VPlayer9.swf` and `APlayer9.swf`. They are compatible with the (somewhat outdated) Flash Player 9 plugin that is bundled with Adobe Reader for Linux ***9.4.1*** and can be used for producing PDF documents with embedded video (MP4/H.264) and audio (MP3) which target this particular Linux version of Adobe Reader.

Alternatively, any Flash-based media player found on the Web which is Flash-9 compatible and which can be configured via FlashVars could be used. (Though the number of such players should be decreasing with the advent of newer Flash versions.)

**NB:** Flash and media playback was dropped in more recent Readers. AR-9.4.1 is the last version on Linux which supports Flash.

Adobe Reader 9.4.1 for Linux can be downloaded from
ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.4.1/.

Example code using `cube.mp4` and `VPlayer9.swf` from the `media9` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}[2013/11/04]

\begin{document}

\includemedia[
  width=0.6\linewidth,height=0.6\linewidth,
  activate=pageopen,
  transparent,
  addresource=cube.mp4,
  flashvars={
    source=cube.mp4     % same path as in addresource!
   &loop=true           % loop video
   &scaleMode=letterbox % preserve aspect ratio
  }
]{}{VPlayer9.swf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know how to make `includemedia` to use the `jw-player` engine? I understand that `media9` is supposed to replace `flashmovie`, however if I use `VPlayer9.swf` the video plays with a lot of flicker and autoloop doesn't work well. If use `flashmovie` with `jw-player` I don't have this problem.

Comment: @alfC: Replace `VPlayer9.swf` with `player_flv_maxi.swf`. The Flasvars option should read `flashvars={flv=cube.mp4&autoplay=1&loop=1&showplayer=autohide}`, with `cube.mp4` replaced by the video file of yours, as set by the `addresource` option.

Comment: Finally, `player_flv_maxi.swf` plays as well as `jw-player.swf` (from `flashmovie`) does. `\includemedia[width=0.6\linewidth,height=0.5\linewidth, activate=pageopen,
transparent, addresource=cube.mp4, flashvars={flv=cube.mp4&autoplay=1&loop=1&showplayer=autohide}]{}{player_flv_maxi.swf}`. The only problem (feature!) is that one has to match the width and height of the video to avoid the black box of the player.

Comment: @alfC: `VPlayer` offers a number of scaling options one can chose from: `letterbox` (best fit), `none` (the way jw-player behaves), `stretch` (no black margins at all), `zoom`. Could you make the video file available for download which produces the reported problems in VPlayer?

Comment: My last concern (black box proportions) is addressed completely by using a poster image and automatic width or height.

Comment: @alfC Could you please post the configuration options (FlashVars) you used for automatic width and height setting?

Comment: 1) `VPlayer9` doesn't work well with Acrobat Linux (9.4.1), specially with autoloop. 2) Unfortunately, I can't make the download available. Let me just say that is quite high resolution (800x800) and plays well with `jw-player` autoloop (and `flashmovie`).3) Automatic size is achieved by removing the `height/width` options and adding poster that is a screenshot of the first frame: `\includemedia[activate=pageopen, flashvars={...}}{\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{cube.png}}{player_flv_maxi.swf}` 3) where are the options for `player_flv_maxi.swf` 4) Can I use `jw-player` alternatively?

Comment: `player_flv_maxi.swf` flashvar options: http://flv-player.net/players/maxi/documentation/

Comment: @alfC: Thanks a lot for the information. As for (4), you can use any Flash-based player that is Flash-9 compatible and which can be configured using FlashVars.

Comment: ok, I wasn't setting the `flashvars` for `jw-player` incorrectly. `\includemedia[activate=onclick,addresource=cube.mp4,
flashvars={file=cube.mp4}
]{\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{cube.png}}{jw-player.swf}`. I would say though, `player_flv_maxi` seems to work better.

Comment: Sorry to bother again. I can't make any of the `media9` solutions work better than the `flashmovie`. I was hoping I could move on to `media9` but the playback is always choppy and unstable (in Acrobat 9.4.1, the only one I can use), the switch otherwise makes sense because `media9` is more powerful. Perhaps you can tell me exactly what is the `media9` code (and options) to replace this `flashmovie` code: `\flashmovie[auto=1,loop=1,controlbar=1,engine=jw-player,width=7.6cm,height=5.2cm,image=cube.png]{cube.mp4}` which works perfect©.

Comment: @alfC Could you send me a link where to download `jw-player`? Btw, I am still working on the playbutton look.

Comment: Good question, I don't know where I got it from, I don't even know if `flashmovie` is using the same version I have in the directory (because it works even if remove it locally) [that could be the reason of the different between `flashmovie` and `media9`]. I downloaded it again from here http://www.jwplayer.com/sign-up/ but it is a much newer version (162436 bytes vs. 113505 bytes).

Comment: I am afraid this new version is not flashplayer-9 compatible which is mandatory for ar-9.4.1, isn't it?

Comment: ok, disregard last comment. I found all the old versions here: http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/browser/tags . Where can I find the `jw-player` that `flashmovie` uses in my computer then?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13652/discussion-between-alfc-and-alexg)

Comment: For the record: `\includemedia[width=0.49\linewidth,height=0.3\linewidth,activate=pageopen,addresource=cube.mp4,flashvars={file=cube.mp4&screencolor=white&image=cube.png&autostart=true&repeat=always}]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{cube}}{player.swf}`

Comment: @alfC. `player.swf` is configured to use `cube.png`. Therefore it must be embedded into the PDF as a resource: `...,addresource=cube.png,...`.

Comment: that explains why I see garbage before the movie runs. And why I didn't see it with `flashmovie`. Can you add something like the simple `flashmovie` commnand to `media9` in which not so much redundant information is needed? (I know the `flashvar` options will depend on the engine but these can hard coded for each `engine=` options. I'll try to write a `newcommand` as a first attempt. Also, did you figure out which version of `player.swf` I was using? It really has no match in terms in compatibility of Linux Acrobat 9.4.1.

Comment: I found the exact player that work very well for me with Acrobat 4.9.1 here: http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/browser/tags/mediaplayer-5.10 . Of the jw-player family this is one of the few players that work with Acrobat 4.9.1, version 4 or 6 don't work.

Comment: By playing with `jw-player` I determined that the main problem with other viewers at playing a repeated short video is the `bufferlength`. Unfortunately I don't see such option in `VPlayer[9].swf`, not at least documented here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?csw=1

Comment: I created an `includemovie` command in my edit to the question to summarize this discussion.

Comment: @alfC: Thank you for providing the wrapper macro. It is certainly useful for other users. Nevertheless, I prefer not to add such a wrapper because it would be player-specific. I want to keep the generic interface for embedding Flash.

Comment: I understand, no argument about that. I had to do it to make it practical to use, specially for the fallback and other mostly redundant information. One thing I noticed is that `flashvars` for the players and options I tried do not interfere with each other, options not understood by a player are ignored. They can be passed independently of the player specification. So, it seems that a convenience command like this is quite flexible and general `\includemovie[DimensionSpec]{PlayerSWF}[flashvars]{MovieFile}[PictureFile]`.

Comment: Is it possible to make `attachfile2` to reuse a file included as `addresource` or viseversa? The idea is to avoid attaching the file twice.

Comment: @alfC. In principal, yes. I will be looking into it. The problem is that several media and auxiliary files as well as the media player itself may belong to one RichMedia inclusion, which renders a single clickable area useless. But the files could appear in the file-attachment pane of the viewer.

Comment: A possible route: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19117/attach-displayed-image-to-the-pdf-without-storing-it-twice . (In my summary of the solution, the clickable attachment is behind the movie so it is visible (and clickable if the movie/rich media) doesn't show up.)

Comment: @alfC: The feature you are looking for was implemented in the `movie15` package, were a file attachment annotation was placed behind the `Screen` annotation and which was accessible in PDF viewers that did not support the `Screen` annot. There is, however, a problem with the `RichMedia` annotation (used by `media9`): In the non-activated state, AR *always* renders it *behind* any other annotation of different type (Link, FileAttachment, ...), even if it is inserted a-posteriori by LaTeX.

Comment: @alfC: (Cont'd)  Therefore, you cannot activate a RichMedia by click in AR if there is another annotation at the same place on the page. Thus, only the file attachments pane in the Reader GUI is usable for opening the media file or downloading it from the PDF.

Comment: Yes, that is why in my solution I had to put the "play button" (really "|>") to a side. Still I think this is a detail with respect to the feature of having access to the media through normal PDF attachments. no? Thanks for your ongoing effort on `media9`!

Comment: still the activated areas seems to be a minor detail one can put the link to the side of the image. Is possible to attach the resource both as embedded/attached2 file and as flash resource without duplicating the data?

Comment: @alfC Just uploaded a new version (0.44) to CTAN. It provides package and command option `attachfiles`. Media and player files can be opened or downloaded from the PDF via the File Attachments Pane of AR.

Answer (score 20):

**Update** Thanks to @percusse for pointing out in his comment that the original answer was not the one the OP was asking for.

So I did a little searching and found this [link](http://abarry.org/the-complete-guide-to-embedded-videos-in-beamer-under-linux/#more-61). Basically, the workaround is,

1. Install [Adobe Reader 9.4.1.](ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.4.1/enu/)
2. Install `flashmovie` or copy it to your source folder (especially the `player_flv_maxi.swf`)
3. Write `\includepackage{hyperref}` and `\includepackage{flashmovie}` in your preamble. A minimal working environment would be:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \includepackage{hyperref}
   \incldepackage{flashmovie}

   \begin{document}

   \flashmovie[width=12cm,height=8cm,engine=flv-player,auto=1]{movie.flv}

   \end{document}
   ```

It seems that, in Linux, you can only get embedded videos in Acrobat with Acrobat version 9.4.1. (Why this is, I don't know yet.) You will also need to install `ffmpeg` to convert your videos to `flv`

I downloaded the sample `text-flv.tex` file from the link. How `flashmovie` works is summarized in this file.

I can verify the claim of that the movie cannot play on the output pdf on my Adobe Reader with version 9.4.7. Opening the pdf gives a message `A 3d data parsing error has ocurred.` I can also verify that it works like a charm in Adobe Reader 9.4.1.

BTW, I have TeX version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13.

**Update: If you are not after embeding** First, make sure that you have installed all required packages to run your movie format. You will need to load the package `movie15,` which comes with `TeXLive 2012.` The manual says that this package is already obsolete and that you should consider using `movie9` instead, which is in `ctan` but not in `TeXLive2012.` I used `movie15` in this answer.

Try the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{movie15}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \includemovie[poster,text={\small(Loading Video...)}]{3cm}{2cm}{movie.mp4}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The `poster` option inserts the first frame of the movie. The `text` option appears before the movie is loaded into your pdf viewer. 3cm and 2cm are the width and height of the frame and `movie.mp4` is the name of your movie.

Run `pdflatex movie.tex` where `movie.tex` is your tex file. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I use `evince 3.4` to view the pdf. Just type `evince movie.pdf` in your terminal. Click on the frame to play the movie. The movie will open with your default movie viewer.

I haven't tried `movie9` though.

**Update** This is in response to User 17791. My previous comment to his answer was deleted when the question was edited by moderator. Here it is, @User17791:

```
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
kpathsea version 6.1.0
Copyright 2012 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.5.10; using libpng 1.5.10
Compiled with zlib 1.2.7; using zlib 1.2.7
Compiled with xpdf version 3.03
```

Below are two snapshots of my desktop with a movie being played in Acrobat 9.4.1. (It's a video of a ritual dance here in Baguio City.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is nice but OP specifically asks for *embedded* playback.

Comment: Thanks hpesoj626 for your detailed answers. I have succeeded in getting a beamer+flashmovie+AR 9.4.1 to work, creating
an avi movie from jpg images using mencoder, and converting the avi movie
to mp4 with ffmpeg. My distro was Fedora 16 When I say to work, I mean I was able to put AR in presentation mode, and
clicking on the image, the movie played. I was able to pause the movie also. BUT: Unfortunately, I have some days ago upgraded to Fedora 17. Repeating all the steps, I am able to see the movie in presentation mode, but
when I want to change to the next slide, AR crashes. So, now I am comp

Comment: hpesoj626, could you please post the output of
pdflatex -v ? So I can compare the libraries it is compiled against, and
I am able to figure out why AR crashes,even following all your
steps. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Fiz65, I am sorry but I have never even tried using Fedora. Did you still have the same settings for AR and your TeX though?

Comment: Thanks, I think you hit the nail on the head: Acrobat Reader 9.4.1 and `flashmovie` is the only combination in which I was successful in embedding (displaying) movies in PDF, and only with the default players (not the fancy ones). I did not succeed using `movie15` or `media9` yet. Also I can confirm some crashes when changing pages that Fiz65 reported.

Comment: @alfC Personally, I prefer using portable VLC for my video presentations. As with Acrobat, I don't use it that much too. But that's just me.

Comment: The only reason to use Acrobat is the embedded movies. An idea solution would be to embed the movie when possible and otherwise (other version of Acrobat or other viewers) fallback to normal attachment/external link.

Comment: @alfC: Upto 9.4.1 Adobe Reader for Linux had the FlashPlayer built-in. Afterwards it was removed by Adobe. The version of the last built-in Player was 9.x. Therefore it could not render newer SWF content, such as the media players that ship with media9 and which require Flash-10.x player. If you want to use media9 with AdobeReader-9.4.1, try the `player_flv_maxi.swf` that flashmovie is using, instead of `VPlayer.swf`. It is FlashPlayer-9.x compatible, but only plays FLV video, not MP4+h.264.

Comment: @alfC: I must correct myself. Even MP4+h.264 plays in `player_flv_maxi.swf` in AR-9.4.1.

Comment: @hpesoj626, it takes some coding but with `media9` (see the other answer, by AlexG) one can have the best of both worlds. Because there is alternative code that the viewer will interpret if the flash code cannot be rendered.

Comment: evince worked fine for me. Okular worked in one of my laptops but it did not in the other. Any hint about why ocular would not work?

Answer (score 8):

I was trying to do same as you and this worked to me

```
\documentclass[unknownkeysallowed]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{multimedia}

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}[allowframbreaks]

\centering

\movie[height = 6cm,width = 6cm,showcontrols] {}{QuantumHallEffectExp.mp4}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

And in order to see what was embedded it is necessary to use Okular in presentation mode.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I tried reading playing an embedded video in Okular, but it doesn't work. Did you do anything in particular? What version of okular are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Linux, and this works for me:

First I have to download `movie15_dvipdfmx.sty` and rename it to `movie15.sty`, and put it in the same directory as my `.tex` file.

Then:

```
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{movie15}
[....]

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includemovie[inline=false,text={\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{play-movie.png}}]{}{}{movie.mp4}
\end{figure}
```

In Linux, I can open the PDF with the viewer `evince`, and the image can be clicked and the movie will play in a separate window.