# Embedding videos using media9

Tags: media9

I'm really new to LaTeX and I'm not very good with computers. I'm trying to put videos into my PDF's. I'm using `media9` and I've got the following going so far.

```
\usepackage{media9} 

 \includemedia[
    width=0.6\linewidth,
    height=0.45\linewidth,
    addresource=/Users/tristanjohnson/Library/texmf/tex/latex/misc/media9/Ruinn.MP4,
    activate=onclick,
    deactivate=onclick,
  ]{Movie}{Ruinn.MP4}

\mediabutton[ mediacommand=some_dice:playPause, overface=\color{blue}{\fbox{\strut Play/Pause}}, downface=\color{red}{\fbox{\strut Play/Pause}}
]{\fbox{\strut Play/Pause}} \mediabutton[
mediacommand=some_dice:setSource [(random.mp4)] ]{\fbox{\strut random.mp4}} \mediabutton[
mediacommand=some_dice:setSource [(cube.mp4)] ]{\fbox{\strut cube.mp4}}
```

I merely copied and pasted the `mediabutton` stuff. When I hit "Typeset" it runs without any errors. But when I click the play button nothing happens. I want the video embedded in the PDF so other people can see the video without having to have the file locally. Help?

Comment: Your media file `Ruinn.MP4` resides at an uncommon place, probably within the TeX installation. Don't clutter a TeX installation with user generated documents and related files. Keep user data separate from software.

Comment: What do you need the media buttons for?

Answer (score 17):

Media files to be played back are usually embedded into the PDF (although playing files from remote URLs via http and rtmp protocols is supported too).

Media9 implements playback of media files inside PDF documents using the FlashPlayer plugin in Adobe Reader. This feature is currently available on the Windows and OSX platforms.

Two prerequisites are necessary: The media file (a video in the MP4/H.264 or FLV formats) and a media player in the Flash format (e. g. `VPlayer.swf` provided by Media9).

The latter is embedded by setting it as the last argument of `\includemedia`, while option `addresource=...` instructs LaTeX to physically embed a video file into the PDF.

Furthermore, `VPlayer.swf` needs to be told what to play. Flash applications are configured via FlashVars. For this, `\includemedia` provides the `flashvars` option. The most important FlashVar of `VPlayer.swf` is `source=...` which sets the media source. More FlashVars exist, e. g. for setting the sound volume, or `loop` which tells `VPlayer.swf` to infinitely replay the video. Refer to the Media9 documentation for other configuration options.

It is a good idea to place media files for embedding into the directory of the document you are about to write, or into a sub-directory of it. Lets assume `Ruinn.MP4` is in the subdirectory `videos`. A minimal working example would read:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

\includemedia[
  width=0.4\linewidth,
  height=0.3\linewidth,
  activate=pageopen,
  addresource=videos/Ruinn.MP4,
  flashvars={source=videos/Ruinn.MP4}
]{}{VPlayer.swf}

\end{document}
```

Note that the paths to the video file used with the `addresource` option and with the `source` FlashVar must be identical. Further note, that MP4 is only a container file format for video. The video data inside the file must be encoded with the H.264 codec. Another option is the FLV file format.

Comment: I'm using Linux, can I specify a player other than `VPlayer.swf`?

Comment: You will need the older AdobeReader version 9.4.1, the last one with embedded FlashPlayer. The you can use `VPlayer9.swf`.

Comment: @YanKingYin : For further instructions, see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70931

Comment: Can I skip the `VPlayer9.swf` if I convert my video to SWF format?  I use Adobe Reader 9.5.5 and it fails, but I don't want to be stuck with an older version.

Comment: Yes, but you won't have playback control (play, pause, stop, fast forward, volume increase, etc.,  etc.). In any case, if you want playback of SWF inside Adobe Reader you need the old version 9.4.1 .

Comment: I don't want to use the old Acrobat Reader, anyway I switched to `movie15`, and it's still not supported by AR, but it works in `evince` in Linux.