# PDF video Embedding Problem

Tags: beamer, media9

I have embed an mp4 video in the PDF file as given below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Title}

\includemedia[
width=\paperwidth,height=0.7\linewidth,
activate=pageopen,
flashvars={aaa.mp4 &autoPlay=true}
]{}{C:/Users/name/Desktop/aaa.mp4}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

There is no compile time error in the code but after running it this massage comes along a  blank pd f file....

"To view the Flash @R Technology content in this pd f file, please install the required version of Flash Player"

I would like to add here that I already have installed the latest version of Flash Player(Adobe Flash Player 12 ActiveX).
So,Can anyone tell what version is required to be installed to obtain Video in pd f file.

Answer (score 4):

1. For Adobe Reader on Windows you need the Flash Player plugin for Firefox, not the ActiveX version for IExplorer. See: http://acrobatninja.blogspot.de/2013/02/flash-player-in-acrobat-family.html
2. Your code has some errors, use the following instead:

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Title}

\includemedia[
  width=\paperwidth,height=0.7\linewidth,
  activate=pageopen,
  addresource=aaa.mp4,
  flashvars={source=aaa.mp4&autoPlay=true}
]{}{VPlayer.swf}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank You!! But what is VPlayer.swf here???

Comment: `VPlayer.swf` is the video player flash component that is installed with the `media9` LaTeX package. It doesn't need to be copied into the current directory.

Comment: Your code also worked for me, even though other codes didn't. However, I can't understand what are the errors that you pointed out in his code. Care to elaborate a bit more, please?

Comment: @AlexG Forgot to say that I meant errors other than the obvious ones: lack of `addresource=aaa.mp4` and lack of `VPlayer` as last argument.

Comment: @TomCho Which errors are you referring to? Note that media playback in PDF/Acrobat Reader still relies on the FlashPlayer plugin. Perhaps this [↗topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102600/1053) answers your questions.