# Media9 is not working when embedding video into beamer

Tags: beamer, media9, embedding, multimedia

I have a problem when I try to insert videos into a beamer presentation. I am currently using the package `media9` to load the video and my .tex file looks like the following:

```
\documentclass[utf8, 10pt, usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[bigfiles]{media9}

\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Madrid}}

\title{Test}
\author{John Doe}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}


\begin{frame}

\centering
\includemedia[width=0.4\linewidth, height=0.3\linewidth]{}{mmc7.mp4}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I am using Overleaf (https://www.overleaf.com/3113609pgjpqt#/8669282/) and I'm opening the document using Preview in OSX. I have also tried using TeXMaker + MikTek in Windows and opening the file using Adobe Reader and I still got the same problem.

Something that looks like a video box shows in the corresponding slide but it can't be played. I have also tried using the package `multimedia` instead of `media9` and I still get the same problem.

What is wrong with my code? How could I fix it?

Comment: Wrong use of `\includemedia` plus wrong PDF viewer. AdobeReader is required. For example, take the code in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155378 and replace all occurrences of `aaa.mp4` with your `mmc7.mp4`.

Comment: @AlexG Thank you, the movie is playing now. Do you know any way of being able to play movies using OSX Preview? If you post your comment as an answer I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: Based on my own experience, Adobe Reader is necessary but not sufficient. Flash Player is needed as well. The point is that Adobe Reader can call Flash Player (and Flash Player can call, say, Adobe Reader). So due to some safety issue such calling function is not supported by most PDF readers.

Comment: @Symbol1 All popular Web-Browsers for Desktop OSs use FlashPlayer as a plugin and allow for the two-way communication you are describing. I am pretty sure it is simply due to the lack of interest that FlashPlayer support is missing in alternative PDF viewers rather than security concerns.

Comment: @AlexG I am surprised to hear that web browsers support such two-way communication because what I experienced is that Safari/Chrome do not show flash in PDF. I am glad to see if I did something wrongly or if there are reasons stopping them from showing flash in PDF.

Comment: @Symbol1 : Of course not in PDF, but in web pages. I just wanted to point out the HTML+SWF / PDF+SWF analogy. PDF viewers other than AR have never implemented SWF support and thus cannot have dropped it.