# Specify media path to add a animation in beamer tex

Tags: beamer, animations, embedding, media9

I need to add an .avi to my beamer-tex presentation. The other posts and the package description do not help me. I may use the `media9` package. But I cannot define a relative media path.

I dont' want to embed a hyperref link or something. There is no absolute path because I will move the file from usb-stick to other computers etc.

When using this:

```
\begin{center}
\includemedia[
    activate=onclick,
    width=0.75\textwidth
]{\includegraphics{stan.png}}{but-wait.avi}
\end{center}
```

it results in a clickable picture which open my working directory and I then may select the movie-file.

I dont' know how to start solving this.

**Maybe a problem of my video programs?**

When I use *sumatrapdf* and click the picture it opens the working directory.

When I use *Adobe* and click the picture just vanishes within the beamer tex (nothing happens).

[image]

Comment: (1) With `media9` the video file is usually embedded into the PDF. (2) Wrong use of the `\includemedia` command. (2a) Video files must be in MP4+h264 format and embedded as a resource. (2b) A video player App, e.g. `VPlayer.swf`, must be embedded and configured to play the video file. See the `media9` manual or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102600 for examples.

Comment: Ok, I converted the file to mp4. It works with Adobe (not with Sumarta). I hope it will work on another PC as well. Thank you very much :)