# No error message, but no output

Tags: media9

Using pdfLaTeX, I attempted to run the code below, which except for the source video is a verbatim copy of code recommended by AGrahn at this link: 
[Embedding videos using media9](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102513/embedding-videos-using-media9?rq=1)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9} 
\begin{document}
\includemedia[
    width=0.4\linewidth,
    height=0.3\linewidth,
    addresource=C:/Janice/67_321.mov,
    activate=pageopen,
   flashvars={source=C:/Janice/67_321.mov}
  ]{}{VPlayer.swf}
 /end{document}
```

There are no error messages, and no output, although the green 'start' button does switch to a white X on a red background.

The console output was as follows:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./media-try.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/media9/media9.sty
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3unicode-data.def)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3experimental/l3str/l3regex.sty
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3experimental/l3str/l3tl-build.sty)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3experimental/l3str/l3tl-analysis.sty
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3experimental/l3str/l3str.sty))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3experimental/l3str/l3flag.sty)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3experimental/l3str/l3str-convert.sty))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/atbegshi.sty
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/atenddvi.sty
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-abspage.sty
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-base.sty
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-lastpage.sty
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/atveryend.sty)))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex)
) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def)))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex)
) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def))
)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
)) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric
.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.t
ex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithm
etics.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.cod
e.tex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code
.tex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.c
ode.tex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)

(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code
.tex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
)))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.st
y)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.st
y)) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarytopaths.code.tex)))) (./media-try.aux)
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))<<VPlayer.s
wf>><<C:/Janice/67_321.mov>>)
*
```

Comment: `/end{document}` does not end the document, but `\end{document}` does.

Comment: What @HeikoOberdiek said, plus, the `*` at the end of your output is actually the prompt from TeX saying "I've processed that, now give me some more input." TeX writes its output file one complete page at a time, and presumably your embedded movie plus the (erroneous but valid) text "/enddocument" is not a full page yet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as noted in comments this is a simple typo.

Comment: Or of course, it's one that's answered correctly; but since it's no real use to anyone, I suppose that the wastebasket category of "off-topic" will do well enough.