# How do I embed a mpg video in Beamer presentation using `media9`?

Tags: beamer, media9, movie15, multimedia

I just read the [documentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCQQFjABahUKEwj03qfXsInJAhUD4CYKHR3IALw&url=ftp%3A%2F%2Fftp.fu-berlin.de%2Ftex%2FCTAN%2Fmacros%2Flatex%2Fcontrib%2Fmedia9%2Fdoc%2Fmedia9.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHSCLjUyeFVDqlzFVcdOtN1dDYrBw&sig2=SvsS8yVyySgccJQbYRkKeA) for `media9` but was not able to identify what I am doing wrong.  The videos in the documentation all play fine in my installation of Adobe Acrobat Pro.  When I compile the example below, the slide has a box for the video that says "(click to play)" but when I click, all I see is white.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
  \includemedia[width=0.6\textwidth,height=0.45\textwidth]{(click to play)}{4x167_h5_k010.mpg}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzH_QCttbrwvRmVyQ0JzaXFFU2c/view?usp=sharing) is a link to the mpg file I am including.  I am actually not sure the aspect ratio of the video.  In addition to even showing up and playing, I am also interested to know the following

1. Do I have to specify both the `width` and `height`?  I would rather specify the width and that it maintain the same aspect ratio.
2. How do I get it to loop (I saw info in the documentation about this, just wanted to get it the play first)?

(I also tried the `movie15` package and that gives a box that is all black)

Comment: Video file must be in MP4/H.264 format. MPEG is not supported. Then copy-paste the example in  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102600 and replace the video file with yours. Yes, you should know the video's aspect ratio beforehand; TeX cannot determine it as it doesn't know anything about video formats. Alternatively, you can `\includegraphics{...}` a still image with appropriate aspect ratio instead of `(click to play)`.  Then zero or one of `width=` or `height=` is required if further scaling is needed.

Comment: @AlexG, I will look into this.  It is surprising that deprecated package, `movie15`, supports MPEG but the replacement package, `media9`, does not.  Hopefully this is the primary problem in my implementation.

Comment: H.264 is much better than MPEG. Surprisingly small files at superior quality.

Comment: @AlexG, I am sure it is better.  I do not think that warrants removing functionality, limiting the possible uses.  I expect this could be related to changes in Adobe, the plugins, or with the goal that videos are viewable in more readers than just Adobe.

Comment: That is the case. The method implemented by `media9` makes use of Flash which restricts the viable media formats to FLV (already obsolete), H.264, MP3 and SWF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @AlexG for directing me to [his solution for a closely related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102600/61946).  On closer review, there is no option to include mpg videos in `movie15`.  This functionality has been deprecated together with `media9`.  The newer package only accepts the more compressed, mp4 format.

I used [`ffmpeg`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) to convert my mpg file to an mp4 file with the command:

```
ffmpeg -i 4x167_h5_k010.mpg 4x167_h5_k010.mp4
```

As a note, `ffmpeg` would not do the conversion until I had a standard aspect ratio.  I had created the video using the `Movie Maker` extension of [VMD](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/).  To obtain a 3x4 aspect ratio, I used the command `display resize 1280 960`, then regenerated the mpg video file.

Here is the final working example (with the video loop command):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
  \includemedia[
    width=0.8\linewidth,
    height=0.6\linewidth,
    activate=pageopen,  
    addresource=4x167_h5_k010.mp4,
    flashvars={
      source=4x167_h5_k010.mp4
      &loop=true  % loop the video
    }
  ]{}{VPlayer.swf}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for VMD, that's exactly what I was doing!