# How to embed mov or mpg files using latex-dvips-Acrobat in 2023 for Adobe Reader?

Tags: media9, multimedia, movie15

In latex, in the past, adding mpg and films was possible with the media9 and then with the movie15 packages. The second package uses Flash, which is obsolete now. (I am not sure about the first.)
In the old times, all this could be watched with Adobe Reader.
(Btw, I work on a mac, and want to make a few pdf files with embedded mpg and mov files; no sound is included.)

In 2023, all is different. Above all, Flash is gone.
Since everybody is using Adobe Reader, there are many questions:

(1) Can the Adobe Reader handle films at all?
(It seems that the answer is yes.)

(2) Can the latest Distiller (Acrobat 2020) handle films at all when it transforms a ps into a pdf? Which ones? (Adobe Acrobat can do so, see https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/adding-multimedia-pdfs.html - but it is unclear whether Distiller can as well.) Or does one need to use ps2pdf? Can either program embed movies in mpg or mov format?

(3) Is there a standard way for putting films into latex without Flash? Is it possible at all? Or is the idea dead completely?

Comment: According to the [media9 documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/media9) page 3, latex->dvips->ps2pdf/distiller is supported by the package. [This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277853/how-do-i-embed-a-mpg-video-in-beamer-presentation-using-media9) explains how to convert mpg files to mp4 so they're usable by media9. It also seems Adobe hosts a [free service](https://www.adobe.com/express/feature/video/convert/mov-to-mp4) to convert mov files to mp4

Comment: I have no idea about the status in distiller, but you could try this example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/516102/2388 (you will perhaps have to move the example video into your current folder, as distiller/ps2pdf can't use kpathsea to find it).