# Embeded video in beamer

Tags: beamer, multimedia

I am trying to embed a video in a beamer presentation. What I am trying is to use `\usepackage{multimedia}` and in my main code to use the following to add the video:

```
\begin{frame}{movie}
\begin{figure}[h!] 
     \centering    
     \movie{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{1.jpg}}{demo.mp4}
     \caption{caption}
\end{figure} 
\end{frame}
```

However in my pdf I get just the image .jpg and I cant see or play the demo video. What is my problem here?

Comment: Not the right PDF viewer?

Comment: What you mean? I am not using the right pdf viewer?

Comment: Maybe. Capabilities of PDF viewers largely differ.

Comment: I am using acrobat reader.

Comment: Which platform, which version? Note that the method the `multimedia.sty` package implements does not, according to the official PDF specification, support MP4 in A-Reader, but in Okular MP4 video may work.

Comment: Anu suggestion about mp4 video?

Comment: For MP4 and AR on Win or OSX I suggest the `media9` package. See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102600 .

Comment: I ve tried to followed the instructions from the proposed link. When I tried to use the media9 package I got the following error: ! Package l3regex Error: Support package l3kernel too old.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as caused by outdated latex version