# open multimedia in adobe acrobat

Tags: multimedia

I have a beamer file which contains an mp4 movie, when I clic to read it it shows this error message

[image: it asks if I want to replace the file]

it asks if I want to replace the file, I serached in the net and installed the codecs pack, but it still doesn't work, what is the solution?
this is the Latex code

```
\section{Movie}
\begin{frame}{Movie}
   \centering{
      \movie[showcontrols]{\includegraphics[scale=0.10]{play.png}}{Hero.mp4}
    }
\end{frame}
```

I'm using Adobe Acrobat XI

this is my folder

[image: folder]

compiling error after calling media9

[image: compile error]

Comment: It clearly seems that the video was not embedded in the PDF file. It will work if you put the Hero.mp4 file along with the PDF file.

Comment: sorry but I didn't understand, what do you mean by along with the pdf file, in the tutorial I saw, he just put the video on the same folder latex file then add the code and it's working, I did the same

Comment: You mean that `D:\INFO\Latex\testAnimation\Hero.mp4` exists and that the PDF file is in `D:\INFO\Latex\testAnimation`?

Comment: of corse, I've added a screenshot of my folder

Comment: Well, it’s strange. If you create another beamer presentation in a different folder with a different video, does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Package `multimedia` implements the `Movie` annotation of the PDF specification. Acrobat (Reader) does not support MP4 playback in a `Movie` annotation. For MP4 content, use the `media9` package. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102600 .

Comment: I received an error, it said in file media9.sty line 342

Comment: @HindDev :  Without a complete, compilable example it is impossible to sort out the error.

Comment: I'll add a photo of the compiling problem

Comment: @HindDev have you installed the missing package?

Comment: which package, i've never installed a package for latex I don't know how

Comment: If you have an up-to-date TeX installation, such as [TeX-Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc.html), all necessary ingredients are there to compile the example in the linked answer.