# Beamer multimedia: display first then last image of a movie

Tags: beamer, animations, multimedia

Using the rather plain:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multimedia}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \movie{\includegraphics{first_image.png}}{movie.mp4}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I get the first image of the movie in my presentation as a "poster" (cf. beamer doc), which is great. And I can click it in order to launch the movie. But it immediately gets back to the poster (so the first image) once finished, which is not what I want.

What is the simplest way to have the `last_image.png` displayed as a "poster" once the movie ends?

Answer (score 1):

If the PDF is intended to be viewed in Acrobat Reader for Windows or OSX, or in Foxit Reader, you may try package [`media9`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102600) instead of `multimedia`. Its video player `VPlayer.swf` stops at the last frame of the video by default. (Though it can as well be configured to rewind to start after playback.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includemedia[
% width=0.4\linewidth,
% height=0.3\linewidth,
  addresource=movie.mp4,
  flashvars={
     source=movie.mp4
    &autoPlay=true %start playback immediately after loading VPlayer.swf
%   &autoRewind=false %the default
  }
]{\includegraphics{first_image.png}}{VPlayer.swf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I have learned that `media9` was the latest multimedia package to go with. But I cannot get its output read by Evince nor Okular, and there are quite few Acrobat & co in my lab.. Any open alternative ?

Comment: Sorry. Currently, there is no open alternative. Though the Poppler library used by Evince and Okular already implements the PDF RichMedia annotation on which `media9` relies.