# Video in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, multimedia

I want to insert a video in my beamer presentation. I've read a lot of posts about this but many are based on obsolete packages and I still can't figure it out, I get a blank slide.

I'm using media9, I have a .mp4 file (I've read that this is appropiate). I want it to play inside the presentation so the solutions using hyperref to open it with a video player in another window are not useful for me.

This is what won't work.

```
\includemedia[
   width=0.8\linewidth,
   height=0.6\linewidth,
   activate=pageopen,  
   addresource=Multimedia/ayuda.mp4,
   flashvars={
      source=Multimedia/ayuda.mp4
      &loop=true  % loop the video
   }
]{}{VPlayer.swf}
```

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Which PDF viewer are you using?  Different viewers can have different capabilities for playing videos in PDFs.

Comment: Can you try with `adobe reader`?

Comment: If you want to have videos on your PDF slides in linux you should try Okular. Evince, Document Viewer and even Adobe Reader seem to crash when displaying the videos.

Comment: I tried Okular but the problem is I get a blank slide instead of the video :/

Comment: Sounds like Foxit  might be worth a try http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301890/36296