# How can I visualize a video (any light format) in a presentation in LaTex?

Tags: acrobat, movie15

I have tried with this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,letterpaper}
 \usepackage{movie15}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\includemovie[poster,text={\small(Loading Circle.mp4)}]{6cm}{6cm}{Circle.mp4}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It compile well, but when I tried to open the pdf document, I can't see the video correctly because is not installed the correct multimedia player. The error says:

> The media requires an additional player. Please click 'Get Media Player' to download the correct media player. To play the media, you will need to close and restart the application once the player installation is complete

So, I updated my adobe reader to 9.4.7 (last version linux), and still have the same problem.

Are there any way to change the default multimedia which is used by Adobe to reproduce videos? Do I need reproduce a specific video format (I tried with .avi, .mp4, .flv, .swf and .mov), or, on the other hand, are there others pdf visualizers or commands which permits to do this task?

Comment: Linux version of adobe reader is not good at playing multimedia. Moreover, `movie15` is outdated. Use `media9`.

Comment: First, use Acrobat 9.4.1 (still available for download), see here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67663/did-anyone-succeed-in-playing-embedded-movies-inside-acrobat-in-linux

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

I don"t know why it doesn't work, but from what I could read on the net there a few time ago, the package you tring to use isn't the easier.
Anyway, there's the `media9` package that could help you (as suggested by AlexG).

Here, a small working example of it :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{media9}
\begin{document}
Grabbag : %
\includemedia[
  addresource=others/Grabbag.mp3,
  flashvars={
    source=others/Grabbag.mp3
   &autoPlay=true
  }
]{\fbox{ici}}{APlayer.swf} vs 
\includemedia[
  addresource=others/Zero.mp3,
  flashvars={
    source=others/Zero.mp3
   &autoPlay=true
  }
]{Jouer}{APlayer.swf}
\begin{figure}
\centering\includemedia[
width=0.7\textwidth,height=0.4\textwidth,
addresource=others/DirtyTalk.mp4,
flashvars={
source=others/DirtyTalk.mp4
&loop=false % loop video
&scaleMode=letterbox % preserve aspect ratio while scaling the video
}
]{\fbox{Activer}}{VPlayer.swf}
\caption{Dirty Talk, par Wynter Gordon.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

You can replace garbag, zero, dirtytalk by the song/movie that you want.

Hope that help you. Note that you need the correct PDF reader to read the movie/song embded. Thus, when you first clik, it's only activate the media. After, re-clik if necessary to launch it.