# Trouble using ffmpeg to encode a h264 video in a .mp4 container to use with media9

Tags: beamer, pdftex, media9

I can't get an `ffmpeg` encoded libx264 video in a .mp4 container to work with media9 and beamer. The pdf is created using pdfLaTeX. It seems to be some kind of ffmpeg issue since the following work fine:

- The random.mp4 from the media9 package works
- So is the .flv default in `ffmpeg` though the video quality is naturally not as good

  ```bsh
  ffmpeg -i Test.mp4  -sameq Test.flv
  ```

Any video I encode in ffmpeg using

```bsh
ffmpeg -i EB_%03d.png -c:v libx264 -x264opts keyint=30 -r 30 -b:v 1000k -s 640x512 Test.mp4
```

plays flawless in e.g. VLC (and I see the duration bar in the pdf though not the video). `ffmpeg -i Test.mp4` yields for the video stream

```bsh
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p, 640x512, 1021 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 60 tbc
```

which is slightly different from `ffmpeg -i random.mp4`

```bsh
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 170 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 60 tbc
```

Output from `ffmpeg`

```bsh
ffmpeg version 2.0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
built on Oct 19 2013 08:34:03 with gcc 4.7 (SUSE Linux)
configuration: --shlibdir=/usr/lib --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man 
--libdir=/usr/lib --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-debug --disable-stripping 
--extra-cflags='-fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 
-fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -g -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE 
-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/include/gsm' --enable-gpl --enable-x11grab --enable-version3 
--enable-pthreads --enable-avfilter --enable-libpulse --enable-libvpx --enable-libopus 
--enable-libass --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libspeex 
--enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb 
--enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-postproc --enable-libdc1394 --enable-librtmp --enable-libfreetype 
--enable-avresample --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc
  libavutil      52. 38.100 / 52. 38.100
  libavcodec     55. 18.102 / 55. 18.102
  libavformat    55. 12.100 / 55. 12.100
  libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 79.101 /  3. 79.101
  libavresample   1.  1.  0 /  1.  1.  0
  libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
```

The code snippet for media9

```tex
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Here should be a .mp4 video}
\framesubtitle{Apparently, something is wrong with my x264 codec}

\includemedia[
width=3.5in,height=2.8in,
activate=pageopen,
addresource=Figures/Test.mp4,
transparent,
flashvars={
source=Figures/Test.mp4&
autoPlay=true&
loop=true&
scaleMode=letterbox
}
]{\includegraphics{Figures/EB_001}}{VPlayer.swf}
\end{frame}
```

Ideas anybody?

Comment: Embedded `random.mp4` plays in AR, but `Test.mp4` doesn't? Can you make the original `*.png` available for download somehow?

Comment: http://ubuntuone.com/15GDUTXBbYp7KHpCzUW0k8 some 7 Mb. Hope this helps!

Comment: Same problem here. There seems to be a problem with `ffmpeg` rather than with the `x264` library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Choosing the right `libx264` options with `ffmpeg` / `avconv` is a bit tricky.

The following `ffmpeg` command line should produce usable video files (adjust frame `-r ...` and keyframe `-g ...` rates to your needs):

```bsh
ffmpeg -i <input> -vf scale="trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 25 -r 25 output.mp4
```

`<input>` to be replaced by a video file to be transcoded, or a PNG/JPEG/... file sequence with wildcards, e.g. `frame-%d.png` for numbered files `frame-0.png`, `frame-1.png` etc.

Replace `ffmpeg` with `avconv`, if the latter is installed. Both share the same options.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I'll have a look at libav soon, in the mean time, HandBrake works (a crude re-encode).

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67663/did-anyone-succeed-in-playing-embedded-movies-inside-acrobat-in-linux? What option do you use to adjust the frame rate or to compress more (at the expense of quality).

Comment: @alfC: Frames per second is specified with `-r ...`, the number of key frames with `-g ...`. I usually take the same number as with the `-r` option to have one key frame per second. Keyframes come into play when trying to seek within the video using the scrub-bar of whatever player component (e. g. jw-player) is used or the arrow keys of the keyboard with VPlayer.swf. Flash Player can only seek between key frames. As for quality, i have relied on the default settings of libx264 so far; it should be adjusted by setting the bitrate option. –  AlexG

Comment: @alfC See section 'Additional Information & Tips' in https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264 on bitrate and compatibility options.