# beamer : embedded video (.avi) in presentation

Tags: beamer, embedding, video

It's the first time that I'm using beamer to prepare my defense presentation. This is the beamer template that I'm using : [template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/fibeamer-for-the-faculty-of-education-at-the-masaryk-university-in-brno/mwjpghgbpkgz) (`pdflatex` version). In fact, I need to include several videos (`.avi`) in my presentation. I've already tried the different ways proposed in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345431/how-to-include-multimedia-files-in-beamer). None of them worked :

```
\begin{frame}{test.video}
 \includemedia[activate=pageopen,
 width=200pt,height=150pt]{}{resources/video.avi}
 \end{frame}
```

or

```
\begin{frame}{test.video}
\movie[width=8cm,height=4.5cm]{play the video}{video.avi}
\end{frame}
```

or

```
\begin{frame}{test.video}
\includemedia[
  width=0.4\linewidth,
  totalheight=0.225\linewidth,
  activate=pageopen,
  passcontext,  %show VPlayer's right-click menu
  addresource=video.avi,
  flashvars={
    %important: same path as in `addresource'
    source=video.avi
  }
]{\fbox{Click!}}{VPlayer.swf}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{test.video}
\includemedia[
  activate=pageopen,
  width=200pt,height=150pt,
  addresource=video.avi,
  flashvars={%
     source=video.avi% same path as in addresource!
%   &autoPlay=true%    % optional configuration
%   &loop=true%        % variables
  }
  ]{}{VPlayer.swf}
\end{frame}
```

and the last one that I tried and was unsuccessful :

```
\begin{frame}{test.video}
\includemovie{.85\textheight}{.85\textheight}{video.mp4}%
\end{frame}
```

They all create a white empty box that does not do anything. I have converted the videos to `.mp4`, this did not help either. I have installed flash-player for adobe (`version 2019.010.20091`). My operating system is : `macOS High Sierra V. 10.13.6`. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which PDF viewer do you use? Do the [video examples](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/media9.pdf) in the `media9` manual play?

Comment: I use `Adobe Acrobat Reader DC (version 2019.010.20091)`. No, they do not work unfortunately.

Comment: If you click the  [link](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/media9.pdf), the `media9` manual most likely opens in the Web browser, not in AR DC. Download the PDF and open it in AR DC directly. Then, the video examples should play, provided that Flash Player was properly installed.

Comment: Yes, they work perfectly when I open the file using AR DC.

Comment: Ok. Now, convert your avi to MP4. Take the code from the first box in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/345433/36296 and paste it into an empty *.tex file. In the code, replace the m4v file with your MP4 file, compile and open PDF in AR DC.

Comment: I did so. It creates the pdf with the playable box, but this error pops up : `unable to play 'video.mp4'`.

Comment: How did you convert to `video.mp4`? Are you working on Overleaf? If so, would you mind sharing a link to the project? Maybe there is something wrong with the encoding of your MP4.

Comment: In fact, I used an application that I had (Free MP4 Convertor). do you think that the problem is with the conversion? since when I play the .mp4 with VLC, there is no problem. I created the .avi video using this command `ffmpeg -start_number 01 -stream_loop -1 -i frame%02d.png video.avi` from a series of frames that were created by `gnu plot`.

Comment: Oh, nice that you are using `ffmpeg`! Use it to produce the correct MP4 directly from the source PNG files acc. to page 2 of the media9 manual: `ffmpeg -i frame%02d.png -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 30 -r 30 video.mp4`

Comment: Thank you @AlexG. You know, it does not create the video.mp4 from my terminal. there is an error : `[image2 @ 0x7fb083800000] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: png, none(pc)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89978/discussion-between-alexg-and-reyhaneh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in a comment that you generated the video from a series of images. Instead of trying to include the video, I would simply include the images directly.

A short example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xmpmulti}
\begin{document}

    %asuming you images are called "something-0.png" up to "something-16.png" 
    \begin{frame}
        \transduration<0-16>{0}
        \multiinclude[<+->][format=png, graphics={width=\textwidth}]{something}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried but the pdf do not act as a continuous image. Your image is a gif. How can I get a gif from the generated pdf?