# Beamer - mp3 - file does not play

Tags: beamer, media9

For a presentation I need to add a mp3 file. I already followed all steps in the Q&A at [How to include multimedia files in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345431/how-to-include-multimedia-files-in-beamer). My followed MMW does compile but do not deliver any sound at all. Maybe someone can help me.

Latest Flash Player and VLC Player version is installed. Adobe Acrobat Reader is used as viewer.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}
\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\title{Title}
\author{K.}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\begin{document}
        \begin{frame}[plain]
    \maketitle
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{embedded files}
\includemedia[
width=0.4\linewidth,
totalheight=0.225\linewidth,
activate=pageopen,
passcontext,  %show VPlayer's right-click menu
addresource=Woodpecker.mp3,
flashvars={
source=Woodpecker.mp3
}
]{\fbox{Click!}}{VPlayer.swf}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace `VPlayer.swf` with `APlayer.swf`.