# Embedding sound file won't play when converted to PDF (Adobe Acrobat Reader DC)

Tags: overleaf, media9

I've been trying to embed a sound file into my PDF, but unfortunately it won't play when opening the PDF.
At first it asks whether the file is trusted, to which i approve. Then it informs me that the document requires Flash Player, which is not supported after december 2020.

To my knowledge, the error implies that its STILL supported.

The file is embedded into the document like this (Similar to [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345431/how-to-include-multimedia-files-in-beamer)):

```
/includemedia[
width=0.4\linewidth,
totalheight=0.225\linewidth,
activate=pageopen,
addresource=addresource/optaget.mp3,
flashvars={source=optaget.mp3}
]{\fbox{Click!}}{VPlayer.swf}\end{frame}
```

It seems like adobe reader cannot play sound files using flash player anymore?

Comment: Hi there, Tom from Overleaf support here. Note that the inclusion of media with `media9` has been very problematic from the very begining, and it's one of the things we can't help much with I'm afraid. The only suggestion I have is that we post-process the PDF file using `qpdf` after LaTeX's finished its job, and this can interfere with Flash. You can try disabling this step by creating a file `latexmkrc` (without any file extension) in your project's top folder and adding a single line `$qpdf = "/bin/true";` in that file. However, this is just a shot in the darkness, without any guarantees.

Comment: @yo' Ah okay. Thanks for quick response. That would be to complicated for me to execute. Thus the PDF is for a university study. This implies neither of the teachers or representatives has any errors with the PDF. I'll might as well just hand in the sound file separately