# media9 mp4 video not playing

Tags: media9

In theory, media9 should be able to embed MP4 movies into a PDF. The document is compiled fine with PDFlatex, but I get a blank screen when opening it in Adobe PDF on Windows 10.

Below is a minimal TEX example. I created the MP4 movie with Kazam in Ubuntu 18 as a screencast of a couple of seconds, that outputs with codec H264 MPEG-4 AVC part 10 (avc1).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includemedia[
     width=\textwidth,
     height=0.56\textwidth,
     addresource=test.mp4,
     flashvars={
         source=test.mp4
         &autoPlay=true
     }
]{}{VPlayer.swf}

\includemedia[
     width=\textwidth,
     height=0.56\textwidth,
     addresource=test.flv,
     flashvars={
         source=test.flv
         &autoPlay=true
     }
]{}{VPlayer.swf}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If I convert the MP4 to FLV using ffmpeg, then it works, but it takes 5 times more space on disk, and in addition much worse resolution. I am curious if there is a way to fix the MP4 inclusion, as the H264 codec is said to be supported by media9 and Flash Player.

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 test.flv
```

Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround, namely to postprocess the .mp4 output from Kazam following the solution of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141765/201329), but keeping the format as mp4, not flv.

Below the code to make the MP4 movie to work with media9 and Flash player:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -profile:v high -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 300 test_postprocess.mp4
```

Still confusing why this is needed. Is it a bug in kazam or in media9, or in flash player?

Comment: It's FlashPlayer. It is quite picky about codecs.