# How to embed a video in a pdf generated by beamer and read it independently of the file emplacement?

Tags: beamer, animations

I would like to embed a video in a presentation using `beamer`. All is going well until I change the pdf location. Is there any command that enables to integrate that video in my pdf so that I can send it for example by email and it can be read by my friend?

Please here what I use for embedding the video:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Particles with inertia} 
\movie[width=10cm,height=7cm]{Heavy particle pair separation}{twoheavy.avi}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: "All is going well until I change the pdf location." What did it start as and what did you change it to?

Comment: @Adam good! I mean that the video can be read in the pdf when the pdf is located in its creation place. When I change the emplacement of the pdf I get an error message when I arrive in the video! I would like to know whether I can "integrate" the video in my pdf so that it can be read independently of its emplacement. I hope that it is more clear now! Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: You have to change the way you add the video, either use the package `attachfile2` or use this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67663/did-anyone-succeed-in-playing-embedded-movies-inside-acrobat-in-linux

Answer (score 2):

The video embedding method implemented in the `multimedia` package, which is bundled with the beamer class, does not allow for video files physically embedded into the PDF document.

There are other options, as mentioned in the comments. One of them is the `media9` package. For documents targeting the Linux platform see [Did anyone succeed in playing embedded movies inside Acrobat in Linux?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67663)

Comment: Thank you @AlfC for your answers. I think that one need to use the flashmovie package for embedding the video. I downloaded the package from CTAN and install it manually in Windows 7. When I compile the tex file I got error! Any help please? Thank you!