# Video not playing

Tags: media9

I want to play video in pdf using latex. Following is my sample code. When I try to play it, just an empty screen comes and video is not played. My basic requirement is that it should display picture with play/pause and when I play it should play. I could not understand much from media9 package file. Please help

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

\includemedia[label=videofile, width=1.0\textwidth, addresource=srs.mp4,
flashvars={source=srs.mp4}]{\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]
{views}}{VPlayer.swf} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: What viewer do you use to open the pdf?

Comment: I use Adobe reader

Comment: On Linux? If so, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70931 . Otherwise there may be an issue with the video encoding of your file. Does `cube.mp4` from the media9 package play?

Comment: When i run srs.mp4 in pdf through latex audio comes but not video

Comment: Then it is a video encoding issue. Which tool did you use to produce the mp4? Try http://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-mp4 to re-encode the video file into a usable format.

Answer (score 3):

Flash support has discontinued from Dec 2020.
Media9 no longer works as above. Fixes are in [Media9 Alternatives](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516029/129388)