# Is there a way to display both videos and JavaScript animations on a beamer-generated PDF under linux?

Tags: beamer, viewers, animate, multimedia, okular

I use the `beamer` package for presentations and often complement it with `animate` (together with `tikz`) and `multimedia`. `animate` creates embedded JavaScript, playable with `acroread`. `multimedia` embeds videos (avi, mp4, ...) playable via `okular` via some video player available to it (e.g. `mplayer`). Unfortunately I have not found a PDF player capable of displaying both JavaScript and videos under Ubuntu. How can I circumvent this issue? I have an upcoming presentation where I would like to be able to play both types of content.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67663) old thread may still be of some help.

Comment: The problem is that currently there is no actively developed PDF viewer for Linux with a JavaScript engine.

Comment: @AlexG See my (unsatisfying) workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Well, after getting very frustrated about this I finally managed to get both `animate` and `media9` content (using the embedded `VPlayer.swf`, see [How to include multimedia files in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345431/how-to-include-multimedia-files-in-beamer)) to play under Ubuntu 18.04 by installing the latest Windows 10 Adobe Reader via `wine`. To play videos, one also needs to install the Firefox Flash Player plugin via `wine`.

This is a disappointing solution but it will have to do until someone developing native Linux PDF viewers decides to incorporate JS functionality.

---

Update 27/01/2020:

I recently had to make a fresh install on a new machine, so I took the chance to gather the steps. On Ubuntu 18.04.03 this works:

```
sudo apt install wine-stable winetricks winbind
winetricks mspatcha
# Important to get this version of AcrobatDC, newer versions didn't work for me
wget ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/win/AcrobatDC/1800920044/AcroRdrDC1800920044_en_US.exe
wine AcroRdrDC1800920044_en_US.exe
wget https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/labs/flashruntimes/flashplayer/install_flash_player.exe
wine install_flash_player.exe
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution. I have tried the same a couple of times without success on my Linux PC running Gentoo Linux. Could you please extend your answer, including a step-by-step instruction for the installation procedure and perhaps a list of additional packages, libraries etc.?

Comment: @AlexG It could be that you need the latest Ubuntu. I'll try to extend the answer when I have the time. Having to embed the videos is still a bother for large ones. I have even tried a local webserver approach which works, but the loading time is quite long, so not workable for a live presentation in front of an audience. Thanks for developing the media9 package by the way.

Comment: @AlexG See my edit, hopefully this works out for you

Comment: Thanks a lot for adding instructions!