# Recover TeX file back from compiled PDF

Tags: pdf, pdftex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert PDF to (La)TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/how-to-convert-pdf-to-latex)

Has anyone written a piece of code that (at least) tries to reconstruct (standard) LaTeX from a compiled PDF file? I mean, identifying indices and exponents, common fonts, footnotes, linebreaks should mostly be algorithmizable, if somewhat error-prone. Basically I am looking for an approximative section of the map *pdflatex: tex → pdf* which does most of the work, leaving maybe a few minor corrections (but not the whole design) to be done at hand.

No, I am not asking for an auto-plagiarizer tool. I am sure I am not the only one here with data loss issues...

Comment: While many users here are mathematicians there are many non-mathematicians here as well. Writing something like “section of the map pdflatex: tex → pdf” will probably not be universally understood and diminishes your chance of answers (also, we don't have any inline TeX renderer, hence my edit).

Comment: If you want this for your own files because you have lost the source code somehow (as your last sentence suggests), you may want to have a look at [Is there some way to embed LaTeX source code in a PDF file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13187/3323) to prevent this in the future.

Comment: This is duplicate the best ansers are available here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/how-to-convert-pdf-to-latex

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [InfinityReader](http://www.inftyproject.org/en/index.html). It is designed to convert OCRed text to latex (and does a fairly good job at that). I don't know if it can directly read pdf files.