# How would I recursively add the document source code to an appendix?

Tags: listings, sourcecode, source

For kicks, I would like to include the source code as an appendix. It's rather superfluous, yes, but it's puzzling.

I commonly have documents that are structured thusly:

```
main.tex
includes: part_1.tex
          includes: subsection_a.tex
          includes: subsection_b.tex
          .... etc
includes: part_2.tex
.... etc ....
includes: appendix.tex
```

I'd like to programatically traverse my document (as a whole), and extract the source code for everything except code listings, then include this extracted source-code as a code listing in the appendix. Does anyone have an idea on where to start?

Comment: So, within (say) `subsection_a.tex` there is a (say) `lstlistings` environment that you want to *exclude* from the inclusion? Since it's close to Christmas, do you want cookies with that too? `:)` Okay, seriously, how about just *attaching* the source code to your output PDF rather than including it in a typeset form?

Comment: Attaching the code to the PDF: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13187/is-there-some-way-to-embed-latex-source-code-in-a-pdf-file

Comment: I removed the thanks. This is just the style here, intended to keep the questions clear. The best way to thank people is to upvote the answers that are helpful to you.

Comment: This is probably much simpler with tools externals to TeX. Consider using a few lines of shell, perl or python to do that instead;

Answer (score 1):

You could use the *DocStrip* program to do this.  That would still be an entirely TeXnical solution!

Split up your document as you've used to, however, instead of using `\input` use *DocStrip* to yank together all the files in the correct order. (Of course, you can still use `\input` to source out text that occurs at multiple places.)

*DocStrip* allows you to selectively include/exclude portions of code.  For your listings, you could write

```
A common operating system is basically coded like this:
%<*listings>
\begin{lstlisting}[language={[Sharp]C}]
try
{
    do_weired_stuff();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    show_blue_screen();
}
\end{lstlisting}
%</listings>
```

Now, if you tell *DocStrip* to `\generate{\file{doc.tex}{\from{doc.dtx{listings}}}` it will write the complete code as shown above to `doc.tex` (assuming the sample is in the file `doc.dtx` of course). If the `listings` is omitted, everything between `<*listings>` and `</listings>` will be skipped. This way you can make *DocStrip* yank together two documents and then `\lstinputlisting` the latter at the end of the former.

I have made a simple demonstration basically featuring the structure of your post.  I don't seem to be able to upload it here but you can get it from [here](http://klammler.eu/data/LaTeX/demos/selfappendix.tar.gz).

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a solution for the cookies yet.  Perhaps if someone else has an idea: please post it!