# Find out which packages are used

Tags: packages

I have written a LaTeX Document and it compiles fine on my machine, but now I would like to give the sources to someone else. Is there a quick way to list all the packages that have been used for compilation?

Comment: difficult. You should use Tex Live anyway which has all you need packaged.

Comment: I didn't install the TeX distribution but it seems that TeX Live is used in some way as it occurs a lot of times in the generated lag file.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yes. Add `\listfiles` somewhere in your document preamble. The output should be posted in your `.log` file. Here's an example from a test document containing 2 packages in the preamble and compiled using TeX Live 2009:

```
\documentclass{article}
\listfiles
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

The `.log` file now includes

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   array.sty    2008/09/09 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
hyperref.sty    2010/05/04 v6.81a Hypertext links for LaTeX
 ltxcmds.sty    2010/04/26 v1.7 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
kvsetkeys.sty    2010/03/01 v1.9 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2010/01/28 v1.3 Prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2010/03/01 v1.9 Provides hex, PDF name and string conversions 
(HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2010/04/01 v0.9 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2010/01/28 v2.1 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Switches for detecting VTeX and its modes (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2009/01/23 v0.5 Provides ifxetex conditional
 hycolor.sty    2009/12/12 v1.6 Color options of hyperref/bookmark (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2009/12/12 xcolor patch
letltxmacro.sty    2008/06/24 v1.3 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2010/05/04 v6.81a Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable integer calculations (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
kvoptions.sty    2010/02/22 v3.7 Keyval support for LaTeX options (HO)
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  bitset.sty    2007/09/28 v1.0 Data type bit set (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2007/11/11 v1.1 Expandable big integer calculations (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2010/03/25 v1.12 At begin shipout hook (HO)
 hpdftex.def    2010/05/04 v6.81a Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
atveryend.sty    2010/03/24 v1.5 Hooks at very end of document (HO)
rerunfilecheck.sty    2010/03/16 v1.6 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2009/12/18 v1.1 Provides unlimited unique counter (HO)
 nameref.sty    2010/04/30 v2.40 Cross-referencing by name of section
refcount.sty    2008/08/11 v3.1 Data extraction from references (HO)
gettitlestring.sty    2009/12/18 v1.3 Cleanup title references (HO)
 ***********
```

So, you can see that loading *only* [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) and [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) (say), actually loads a large number of other packages as well.

Comment: Great, thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I have some recollection of a script that uses `\listfiles`to actually bundle up all files that are belonging to a particular document for archival purposes. Anybody having a pointer?

Comment: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=filesused

Comment: Great answer.  Is there a way to only get the 1st level? As in only those that I've explicitly specified in the TeX file, and not those loaded because a package I've used needs them?  Over time, changes occur and you can have quite a list of packages at the top of the document, but I'm not longer making use of maybe 10% of them.

Comment: @TravisBemrose: There is no easy way to do this, as all package inclusions use the same mechanism (`\input` or `\include` or `\usepackage` or ...). One way would be to define a macro `\usemypackage{<package>}` which could accumulate package names, then do a search-and-replace for `\usepackage` in your main document to `\usemypackage`. As such, there's no easy, out-of-the-box solution. Of course, you could just start removing any packages that you think you don't use or are obsolete (see [How to keep up with packages and know which ones are obsolete?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3910/5764).

Comment: That's basically my process right now, remove a `\usepackage`line, compile, check for error, rinse, repeat.  At least this process is of order `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Use the [snapshot package](https://www.ams.org/arc/resources/snapshot-about.html).

The CTAN tag [archival](https://ctan.org/topic/archival) lists tools made for such or similar use cases. For instance, the package [embedall](https://ctan.org/pkg/embedall) can be used to embed all required files into the generated PDF. See [Is there some way to embed LaTeX source code in a PDF file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13187/9075) for a discussion.

In the following, I evaluate `mkjobtexmf` and `snapshot`. I assume the main tex file being `main.tex`.

### [mkjobtexmf](https://ctan.org/pkg/mkjobtexmf)

Preparation: No need for a special modification of `main.tex`

Execution: `mkjobtexmf --jobname main`

Result: Directory `main.mjt`. It contains a sub directory `texmf`, which in turn contains a directory `tex`, where one can find the packages.

`tree` shows following output:

```
└───texmf
    ├───fonts
    │   └───type1
    │       └───public
    │           └───amsfonts
    │               └───cm
    ├───miktex
    │   └───data
    │       └───le
    │           └───pdftex
    ├───pdftex
    │   └───config
    └───tex
        ├───generic
        │   ├───atbegshi
        │   ├───bigintcalc
        │   ├───bitset
        │   ├───etexcmds
        │   ├───gettitlestring
        │   ├───iftex
        │   ├───infwarerr
        │   ├───intcalc
        │   ├───kvdefinekeys
        │   ├───kvsetkeys
        │   ├───ltxcmds
        │   ├───pdfescape
        │   ├───pdftexcmds
        │   └───uniquecounter
        └───latex
            ├───atveryend
            ├───auxhook
            ├───base
            ├───graphics
            ├───hycolor
            ├───hyperref
            ├───kvoptions
            ├───l3backend
            ├───letltxmacro
            ├───refcount
            ├───rerunfilecheck
            ├───tools
            └───url
```

### [snapshot](https://ctan.org/pkg/snapshot)

Preparation: Add `\RequirePackage{snapshot}` at the first line of `main.tex`

Execution: `pdflatex main`

Output: `main.dep`

```
\RequireVersions{
  *{application}{pdfTeX}  {0000/00/00 v1.40.23}
  *{format} {LaTeX2e}     {2021-11-15 v2.e}
  *{package}{snapshot}    {2020/06/17 v2.14}
  *{class}  {article}     {2021/10/04 v1.4n}
  *{file}   {size10.clo}  {2021/10/04 v1.4n}
  *{package}{array}       {2021/10/04 v2.5f}
  *{package}{hyperref}    {2021-06-07 v7.00m}
  *{package}{ltxcmds}     {2020-05-10 v1.25}
  *{package}{iftex}       {2020/03/06 v1.0d}
  *{package}{pdftexcmds}  {2020-06-27 v0.33}
  *{package}{infwarerr}   {2019/12/03 v1.5}
  *{package}{keyval}      {2014/10/28 v1.15}
  *{package}{kvsetkeys}   {2019/12/15 v1.18}
  *{package}{kvdefinekeys}{2019-12-19 v1.6}
  *{package}{pdfescape}   {2019/12/09 v1.15}
  *{package}{hycolor}     {2020-01-27 v1.10}
  *{package}{letltxmacro} {2019/12/03 v1.6}
  *{package}{auxhook}     {2019-12-17 v1.6}
  *{package}{kvoptions}   {2020-10-07 v3.14}
  *{file}   {pd1enc.def}  {2021-06-07 v7.00m}
  *{file}   {hyperref-langpatches.def}{2021-06-07 v7.00m}
  *{package}{intcalc}     {2019/12/15 v1.3}
  *{package}{etexcmds}    {2019/12/15 v1.7}
  *{file}   {puenc.def}   {2021-06-07 v7.00m}
  *{package}{url}         {2013/09/16 v3.4}
  *{package}{bitset}      {2019/12/09 v1.3}
  *{package}{bigintcalc}  {2019/12/15 v1.5}
  *{package}{atbegshi-ltx}{2021/01/10 v1.0c}
  *{file}   {hpdftex.def} {2021-06-07 v7.00m}
  *{package}{atveryend-ltx}{2020/08/19 v1.0a}
  *{package}{rerunfilecheck}{2019/12/05 v1.9}
  *{package}{uniquecounter}{2019/12/15 v1.4}
  *{file}   {l3backend-pdftex.def}{2021-10-18 v3}
  *{-------}{Document-specific files:}{----}
  *{package}{nameref}     {2021-04-02 v2.47}
  *{package}{refcount}    {2019/12/15 v3.6}
  *{package}{gettitlestring}{2019/12/15 v1.6}
  *{file}   {main.out}    {0000/00/00 v0.0}
  *{file}   {main.out}    {0000/00/00 v0.0}
}
```

### [texdeps](https://ctan.org/pkg/texdeps)

This is a tool from 1999 and runs for the MWE. For a real-live document, I aborted it after 5 minutes runtime.

Preparation: No need for a special modification of `main.tex`. perl needs to be installed

Execution: `perl "c:\Users\kopppor\Downloads\texdeps.pl" main.tex`

Result:

```
! kpse couldn't find \Hy@driver.def (in C:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty)
main.tex
C:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/tools/array.sty
C:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
C:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
C:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def
C:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc-greekbasic.def
C:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/hyperref/psdextra.def
C:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref-langpatches.def
C:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/hyperref/puvnenc.def
C:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/hyperref/puvnenc.def
C:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/hyperref/puarenc.def
C:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc-greekbasic.def
```

### Summary and Recommendation

`texdeps` does not find all dependencies for the MWE. Thus, I cannot recommend it at all. Which a MWE, the "output" of `mkjobtexmf` is good to handle. Just open a file explorer and navigate around.

Even though one has to modify its main tex document, I like the output of `snapshot` best, as it lists all external files and categorizes them.