# Is there a way to find out which packages are used (rather than merely called) by a document?

Tags: packages

Is there any way to find out which packages you have loaded in your preamble are actually being used given the (La)TeX that follows?

I don't believe I'm looking for [`\listfiles`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45205/find-out-which-packages-are-used), since as far as I understand that would only return the packages called in the preamble (and whatever packages those packages may have, themselves, called).

What I am seeking to do with this is cut down on unused packages in an unwieldy preamble. I know that I could comment out each package and look for errors, cutting the packages that can be commented out without error. I'd like to know if there is an (at least semi-)automated way to accomplish this same task for when the number of packages is large.

Comment: It's not really possible in general.