# Is Enumerate default?

Tags: packages, environments, enumerate

I'm relatively new to TeX and I'm wondering why I'm able to use `\begin{enumerate}` without importing the package for the article, beamer, and letter document classes. But most users seem to add `\usepackage{enumerate}`. So I'm wondering if the document class imports these automatically (along with other packages), and if so, how I can tell if the packages are imported to avoid redundancy.

Comment: A package may provide totally new set of commands, or it may provide enhanced versions of existing [native] commands.  Examples of the latter variety are the `enumerate` and `enumitem` packages that enhance the native `enumerate` environment, `verbatim` package which enhances the `verbatim` environment, ... etc.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes ah, this makes sense! Thank you! So therefore enumerate and other environments are indeed included in every document class?

Comment: I believe so, in the case of `enumerate` and other similar native environments.  The packages are in response to the frequent wishes that "if only it could do this and that more easily..."

Comment: I never say `\usepackage{enumerate}`. Ever. I frequently have `\usepackage{enumitem}`. However, don't load them with Beamer.

Comment: @rb612 Well, not quite. The "baseline" definitions of `enumerate`, `itemize`, etc are actually defined in a file called `latex.ltx` which is loaded *before* the document class. Some document classes may overwrite those definition without needing to include any other classes. If you include the `enumerate` class explicitly, you overwrite all the previous definitions of the commands. That might be a *bad* idea, if the class redefines `enumerate` to play nicely with some other commands in the class, but the `enumerate` class then deletes those changes!

Comment: ... In fact, you can think of`latex.ltx` as the definition of "what LaTeX actually is" - for example it defines the `\documentclass` command that you use to at the start of your LaTeX input, and many similar things (it's almost 8,500 lines long, in total!)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `enumerate` environment is defined by the LaTeX kernel - the set of macros loaded on top of (or in addition to) the base TeX. This kernel is collected as within [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co), and here's the definition of `enumerate`:

```
4762: \def\enumerate{%
4763:  \ifnum \@enumdepth >\thr@@\@toodeep\else
4764:    \advance\@enumdepth\@ne
4765:    \edef\@enumctr{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}%
4766:      \expandafter
4767:      \list
4768:        \csname label\@enumctr\endcsname
4769:        {\usecounter\@enumctr\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}%
4770:  \fi}
4771: \let\endenumerate =\endlist
```

Note how the `enumerate` *environment* is defined using its *command* or *macro* format. That is, explicitly defining `\enumerate` and `\endenumerate` as being a `\list` with specific properties.

So, there is no need to load the [`enumerate` package](//ctan.org/pkg/enumerate) in order to use the `enumerate` environment; it's just coincidence that the package is named that way. The package provides an optional argument (an extension) to the `enumerate` environment that allows the user to specify certain formatting options (without having to go through the hassle of virtually redefining the way `enumerate` works).

If you wish to find out which packages are loaded (either by the document class or by some other loaded package), see [Find out which packages are used](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45205/5764).

Answer (score 7):

Welcome tex.stackexchange.

The classes that you mentioned in above don't import `enumerate` package. 
This package gives you some facilities to typeset the counter of enumerate environment with desired style. for more details see the package's manual.

As a first example you'll see the following example in the manual:

```
\begin{enumerate}[EX i.]
    \item one one one one one one one
          one one one one\label{LA}
    \item two
    \begin{enumerate}[{example} a)]
        \item one of two one of two
              one of two\label{LB}
        \item two of two
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You do not need any packages to use the very standard LaTeX environments lists, namely `itemize` for bulleted items, `enumerate` for enumerated items and `description` for items starting with bold text, that are particular cases of the more general `list` environment.

These defaults environments could be enough to make any lists in most cases if people were not so picky and finicky, but "*c'est la vie, mon ami*", so this site is plenty about questions about `enumerate`, `enumitem` and [some others](https://www.ctan.org/topic/list) to change easily list behaviours (as change the label of the item, count in reverse order or run­ning sev­eral items per line, etc.)

However, at least at some extent you can also change the standard list formats or create your own type of list without any package. Example:

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent Standard enumerated list: 
\begin{enumerate} 
\item Item one
\item Item two
\item Item three
\end{enumerate}
Modified enumerated list without packages:
\begin{enumerate}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\alph{enumi})}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\Alph{enumi}}
\setlength\itemsep{-1ex}
\setlength\labelwidth{-1cm}
\setlength\labelsep{5ex}
\item Item one
\item Item two
\item Item three
\end{enumerate}
Custom enumerated list:
\newcounter{mycounter}
\begin{list}{\textcircled{\scriptsize\arabic{mycounter}}}%
{\usecounter{mycounter}
\setlength\itemsep{2ex}
\setlength\labelwidth{1em}
\setlength\labelsep{1em}
\setlength\leftmargin{0pt}}
\item Item one
\item Item two
\item Item three
\end{list}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness, the enumerate environment is not available in the [`standalone`](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone) document class.  This MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item foo
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

produces a curious error:

> ```
> ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
> Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
>  ...                                              
>
> l.4 \item f
>            oo
> ```

But standalone is more for documents that produce diagrams, and enumerate isn't needed.

Comment: Note that `\show\enumerate` will demonstrate that `enumerate` is defined and so "available".  What is not allowed in this class is to have `enumerate` as a top level environment; putting it inside e.g. `minipage` will work fine.  `standalone` is looking for "pictures" it can cut out and export.

Comment: Is even more available that in the `minimal` class, where the environment is allowed and the items are showed without error, but  without numbers.