# Figure out which packages have been downloaded (vs. installed by default)

Tags: packages, miktex

Similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45205/find-out-which-packages-are-used), I would like to figure out which packages I am using, with a twist - I'd like to know which of these *are not* included in the generic Miktex distribution, so I can download them and add them to a local configuration-managed repository.

Is there an easy way to do this?

**Edit:** as a point of clarification, with the auto-install option enabled, packages are downloaded from CTAN in addition to what normally is included when miktex is installed. Additionally, some packages have updates downloaded. My question is how to put the whole thing under CM control such that I can be assured that this particular configuration will work for my document templates. I'd like to be able to create my own on-disk package repo from this to run in a closed environment (no internet access).

Comment: Set MikTeX console (Settings/General) to install missed package on-the-fly.

Comment: @Zarko - I don't see what that gets me... it's already set to do this.

Comment: This setting automatic load missed packages during compilation of the your  document in your MikTeX installation (in the most of cases).

Comment: not what I'm looking for.

Comment: What do you mean with 'generic distro'? Files not included should remain in your personal TEXROOT folder. A shell script which uses the output of your referred question's accepted answer should reveal which of those files do not remain in the MiKTeX folder but in your personal folder. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: @Twonky, question edited for clarity.

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but on my system, I can go into tex\latex and view folders by date created/date modified.  All packages installed by default have the same creating date.  Anything updated, will have a later modified date, and anything installed at a later point in time will have a later creation date.