# Hyperref does not work with acro package

Tags: hyperref, hyperlink, acro

I got the following error:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! keyvalue error: "option-unknown"
! 
! Unknown option 'make-links' for package .
! 
! See the keyvalue documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  
                                                  
l.9 \acsetup{make-links=true}
                             
? H
|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| LaTeX has been asked to set an option called 'make-links' but the  package
| has not created an option with this name.
|...............................................
?
```

when compiling

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[hyperref,only-used]{acro}
\usepackage[colorlinks, hidelinks, colorlinks, linktocpage=false, pagebackref=true, breaklinks=false]{hyperref}%
\DeclareAcronym{esri}{
    short = ESRI,
    long = Environmental Systems Research Institute ,
    class = abbrev
}
\acsetup{make-links=true}
%\acsetup{list/display=used}
\begin{document}
\ac{esri}
\end{document}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: That is _very_ strange because `acro` **does not and has never** used the package `keyvalue`. Indeed there is no package `keyvalue` that I know of. If anything you should be getting ``LaTeX3 Error: The key 'acro/make-links' is unknown and is being ignored.``. (That would happen if your version of `acro` was version 2.x.) (An up to date `acro` version 3.x should warn you about the options `hyperref` and `only-used` being unknown and about the property `class` being deprecated.)

Comment: @Stephen where do you get this message from? It is not in the log when I compile the MWE with up to date texlive. From the error message style I'm guessing an older version of expl3…

Comment: @cgnieder: Yes, thus "too old version - please update" is the solution to the problem. Can you provide it as answer, please? Then the question does not need to be closed.

Comment: @Stephen the answer might also be “the option `make-links` does not exist for your version of `acro`, use the option `hyperref` instead”.

Comment: @cgnieder: Well, both: Either using another option or update (which might not be easy or even impossible if it is not ones own computer, on-line-TeX-compiler or whatsoever). Maybe even (pseudo code) `\@ifpackagelater{acro}{ when? }{ make-links }{ hyperref }`.

Comment: @Stephen before I post an answer I like a confirmation by the OP. Until then this is all speculation (albeit a probable one). So far only you posted the error message and confirmed an outdated tex live and not the OP…

Comment: Please could you add `\listfiles` to your preamble and update the question to include the file list it generates in the log? See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45206/106162) for an example.