# Latex Error: Command `\mathdollar' already defined

Tags: errors, compilation-error, posters, tikzposter

How can I fix this code which I was preparing for a poster of training?

```
\documentclass[,landscape]{tikzposter}
\usepackage{empheq,mathtools}
\usetheme{basic}
\author{Marya Blabla}
\title{\Huge Training on Typesetting Math in Ms Word}
\institute{Blabla University} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\DejaSans{DejaVu Sans}

\usepackage{MnSymbol,wasysym}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\block{\LARGE Wait Math in Ms Word?}{
\LARGE
\begin{itemize} 
\item Really?
\item You must be joking!!!!!Whoaaaa
\item Sign me up!
\end{itemize}
}

\note[rotate=8, connection, width = 7cm, 
]{\LARGE Only in 2Hours! }

\begin{columns}

\column{0.7}
\block{\LARGE But, what will be covered?}{\LARGE
\begin{itemize}
\item Almost everything  
\item Everything?
\item Yes, Almost Everything!
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
  \begin{rcases}
\displaystyle f(x)= \frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[a_n \cos(nx) + b_n \sin(nx)] \\
\displaystyle a_0 =\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\ dx  
  \end{rcases}
  \\
  \begin{rcases}
\displaystyle f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n e^{inx}\\  
\displaystyle c_n  = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) e^{-inx}dx,\quad n=0,\pm1,\pm2,\ldots
  \end{rcases}
\end{empheq} 
\end{itemize}
}

\column{0.3}
\block{\LARGE Ok, who is the Trainer}{\LARGE
\begin{itemize}
\item Your trainer see below {\DejaSans }
 
\item Really???
\end{itemize}
}

\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just remove the `MnSymbol` package.

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL really? I will do that.

Comment: A good option is to use the `libertinus-otf` package.

Comment: The message you get (which is generic) indicates that some package has already defined this command, it is best to change the order of the load and comment.

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL so which package should come first?

Comment: That depends `:(`, take a look at (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45206)

Comment: gracias, i will check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to load `MnSymbol` and `wasysym`? I assume you are using `(Lua/Xe)LaTeX` and have better ways to access those symbols (if you need them).

```
\documentclass[,landscape]{tikzposter}
\usepackage{empheq,mathtools}
\usetheme{Basic} % b->B
\author{Marya Blabla}
\title{\Huge Training on Typesetting Math in Ms Word}
\institute{Blabla University}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\DejaSans{DejaVu Sans}

%\usepackage{MnSymbol,wasysym}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\block{\LARGE Wait Math in Ms Word?}{
\LARGE
\begin{itemize}
\item Really?
\item You must be joking!!!!!Whoaaaa
\item Sign me up!
\end{itemize}
}

\note[rotate=8, connection, width = 7cm,
]{\LARGE Only in 2Hours! }

\begin{columns}

\column{0.7}
\block{\LARGE But, what will be covered?}{\LARGE
\begin{itemize}
\item Almost everything
\item Everything?
\item Yes, Almost Everything!
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
  \begin{rcases}
\displaystyle f(x)= \frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[a_n \cos(nx) + b_n \sin(nx)] \\
\displaystyle a_0 =\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\ dx
  \end{rcases}
  \\
  \begin{rcases}
\displaystyle f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n e^{inx}\\
\displaystyle c_n  = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) e^{-inx}dx,\quad n=0,\pm1,\pm2,\ldots
  \end{rcases}
\end{empheq}
\end{itemize}
}

\column{0.3}
\block{\LARGE Ok, who is the Trainer}{\LARGE
\begin{itemize}
\item Your trainer see below {\DejaSans }

\item Really???
\end{itemize}
}

\end{columns}

\end{document}
```