# Embedding a Tex file inside a PDF?

Tags: pdf, embedding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there some way to embed LaTeX source code in a PDF file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13187/is-there-some-way-to-embed-latex-source-code-in-a-pdf-file)

Is there any way to tell XeTeX/XeLaTeX (or pdfTeX/pdfLaTeX) to embed a copy of the TeX file inside the PDF (as an attachment perhaps)?

Comment: using pdflatex, i _think_ you can use attachfile2 (or even attachfile).  never done this myself, just read about the package.

Comment: @cmhughes: Funny, I did a bunch of searches and still didn't run across that... thanks.