# Referencing to CD content

Tags: bibtex

I am moving alot of appendix material to an attached CD with my report. I was wondering if there was a right or wrong way to reference to CD content.

In this case how can this be accomplished? Would you just cite to a reference which points to the CD?

Comment: Did you consider attaching the files to the PDF instead of shipping a CD?

Comment: @Marco, i have already done this, but in my faculty we have guidelines for attachments filling more than 10pages, which all my documents do.

Comment: I am not talking about printing the contents of your files into the chapter “Appendix”, I mean to embed binary files (eg. PDFs) into the main document, see [Is there some way to embed LaTeX source code in a PDF file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13187/is-there-some-way-to-embed-latex-source-code-in-a-pdf-file)

Comment: I'm not clear on whether your question is about bibliographies and citations or, instead, about creating cross-references to "objects" (tables, figures, whole sections and chapters) found in an external document. If it's the latter, you could look into using the `xr` package, which lets you create cross-references to items in an external (la)tex document.

Comment: @Marco, they are already attached in my appendix with the method you linked to, which i have to avoid in this case. Im more interested in the correct method to reference to a CD based appendix. Would you just use a `@manual` template and reference to this? Perhaps im making a way too big deal out of this, and most likely could go with simple reference that points to the filename on the CD.

Comment: @Mico, my question is actually much simpler than that! Sorry for the confusion, but im trying to figure out the correct way to cite (or just reference) a CD based material.

Comment: You can consider the appendices as a separate 'publication' using `@misc` for the whole cd or individual `@incollection` entries for each appendix with `booktitle='My appendix CD'` or something - however, since the appendices are part of the report, you can also choose not to cite them and instead refer to them, i.e., just write _See CD:Appendix 23_ or _See Supplementary Material: List of Things_ or even _See `\href{filename}{some appendix}`_ if you plan to include the report pdf on the CD and distribute it as such to the readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cite a (music?) compact disc using BibTeX, you could use the `@misc` entry type (required fields: none; optional fields: `author`, `title`, `howpublished`, `month`, `year`, `note`). If you're willing and able to use the newer `biblatex` system, you could use the `@audio` or (more specifically) the `@music` entry types.