# How use embedfile package with pdflatex to embed entire tree of source files?

Tags: pdftex, source, files, embedfile

What commands with the `embedfile` package will embed an entire tree of source files into the output from pdfLateX?

The sort of tree, in very simplified form, that I have is as follows, where (d) denotes a directory:

```
                mainsourefile.tex
              /          |             \
       preamble (d)   main (d)     one.bib,two.bib biblatex.cfg, ...
                     /     |        \
               chap1 (d)  chap2 (d)  chap3 (d)
              /     \        :          :
         sec11.tex  sec12.tex
```

That is, aside from the main `.tex` file there are individual files in the same top-level directory as `mainsourcefile.tex`. That top-level directory has several subdirectories (for preamble, frontmatter, mainmatter, backmatter). And the `mainmatter` subdirectory in turn has subdirectories for individual chapters, each such subdirectory consisting of multiple `.tex` files (one for each section of the chapter).

The skeleton of the tree structure is also indicated by the form of `mainsourcefile.tex`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\input{preamble/preamble}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\include{front/frontmatter} 
% frontmatter.tex inputs several files
\tableofcontents

\mainmater
\input{main/mainmatter} 
% mainmatter.tex includes main/chap1/chap1.tex;
%      chap1.tex inputs sec11.tex, sec12.tex. etc.
% mainmatter.tex includes main/chap2/chap2.tex; etc.

\backmatter
\include{back/backmatter}
% backmatter.tex inputes back/indexes.tex, back/bibs.tex.

\end{document}
```

In the documentation for `embedfile` I could not find sufficient examples guiding me how to embed such a tree of files.

Comment: Since posting my question, I've found it sufficient for my purposes to use the `snapshot` package to produce a list of all files used (even though it does nothing like`embedfile`.

Comment: Similar question: [Is there some way to embed LaTeX source code in a PDF file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13187/9075) with [embedall](https://ctan.org/pkg/embedall) as solution.

Comment: Maybe ```\newcommand{\includeFile}[1]{\input{#1}\embedfile{#1}}``` or use renewcommand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except for the shell escape feature (running an external program) LaTeX cannot read directory listings. Also, if a file is included it is not known to the TeX language, where the file comes from. A file can be in the current directory, below the current directory, or it can come from a standard location.

### mkjobtexmf

The `.log` file contains file names with path, but parsing it is no fun because of the undefined structure and the hard line breaks. However, many TeX compiler (pdfTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX) provide a file name recorder by option `--recorder`.
This can be used to detect the input file paths. For example, this is used by the project [mkjobtexmf](https://ctan.org/pkg/mkjobtexmf).

The procedure would be as follows:

1. Run `mkjobtexmf` to generate a directory, which contains all files, used by the LaTeX compilation.
2. Delete unwanted files and maybe add other important source files.
3. Generate an archive file (`zip` and friends).
4. Include the archive file by `embedfile`.
   I do not think it make to much sense to include the sources as many single files.

### Version control system, e.g. `git`

An easier way to get all source files is to ask the version control system for it. As an example, `git` is used.

1. Put the project into version control:

```bash
    cd "Project directory"
    git init .
```

2. Add the source files (`git add`) and commit (`git commit`).
3. Ask the version control system for the files. `git` makes it easy by
   its `archive` feature:

```bash
    git archive --format=zip -o project.zip master
```

This puts all versioned files of branch `master` to the archive file `project.zip`.

4. Include the archive file with `embedfile`.