# bundledoc does not collect *.bib-files when option keepdirs is used

Tags: archiving, bundledoc

Consider this MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{snapshot}
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{filecontents,biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @misc{anything,
  author={A. Anyone}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
 \chapter{My document}
This is my text
\end{document}
```

›Collecting‹ the `bib`-file I can use:

```
bundledoc --include="*.bib" bundledocbib.dep
```

But as soon as I use it with `--keepdirs` as in

```
bundledoc --keepdirs  --include="*.bib" bundledocbib.dep
```

the `bib`-files are omitted.

Comment: I didn't know of the existence of `bundledoc`. It's nice to know.

Comment: It is great! But has some strange behaviours, see as well: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416928/how-to-archive-a-tex-project-by-gathering-e-g-all-figures-and-used-packages

Comment: Nice indeed! I gave thought of this before, on how to store a document for long term. And I thought the only way to assure an identical build would be to store all files, packages and executables involved. Glad to see it is already "bundled". :)

Comment: Write the author and ask him.

Comment: Does anyone know why the *.bbl file is included by biblatex but the *.bib file is not? I would say that the *.bib file is the original source (and therefore clearly a dependency) and was quite astonished that it is not in the *.dep file in the first place.

Comment: Note: Your MWE is _not_ a good MWE as the `.bib` file is _not_ required to build the final document (the first compilation autogenerates the `.bib` file).

Comment: You are right, but the example serves the purpose showing that the `.bib` file is not collected by bundledoc. 
The author of the package/script has been informed about this issue.

Comment: @LukasCB Are the workarounds sufficient? If yes, accepting the answer would be nice. Otherwise, let me know whether the problems persist.

Comment: It works as a workaround but I am still looking for a rather clean solution. Till then I accept(ed) your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Workaround that addresses the bug in bundledoc**

I could reproduce the behavior using TeXlive 2016 on Debian. Apparently there is a bug in the bundledoc script that does not expand the relative path to an absolute path, which is required for the `keepdirs` option.

When I provided the absolute path, the bib file was included with and without the `keepdirs`option.

```
bundledoc --include=`pwd`/*.bib ...
```

I believe this is a reasonable workaround. But Ulrike is right, the package developers should know about this.

**2) Workaround that adds the *.bib file to *.dep**

Also, I found that adding a line

```
*{file} {test.bib} {0000/00/00 v0.0}
```

to the *.dep file lead to correct behavior, i.e., the *.bib file was added to the archive with and without `--keepdirs`. Of course, doing this manually is unconvenient, so one may consider including

```
\makeatletter
\@addtofilelist{test.bib}
\makeatletter
```

in the preamble of the document. Then, the extra option `--include=*.bib` is not required anymore.