# Extract LaTeX code from PDF document

Tags: conversion

Good morning.
If I wanted to extract the LaTeX code from a pdfLaTeX document, what should I do?
Thank you so much.

Comment: You can not extract it, it is not there. You can get the text but would need to re-add the latex markup.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: unless the original author was [thoughtful enough to embed the code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13187/119).... :-)

Comment: @WillieWong yes getting an egg from an omlette is easy if the omlette filling is a raw egg:-)